# Meaning of $this-> in CakePHP

Tags: php, oop, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: self vs. $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

What does `$this->` mean in CakePHP?

Please answer this in two parts...
What does `$this` refer to?
What does `->` refer to?

Can someone explain each part explicitly in terms of the statement $this->Post->find('all'); in the Post controller. Why do you need the ->Post part if it is in the Posts controller?

Comment: Here's a good answer:
[link text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this) It also tells you the difference between $this and self

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$this refers to the class you want to use. for instance if you see $this->Post->find('all'), you're trying to access the class Post that extends AppModel. Through conventions, the Post Model uses the posts table in your database. $this->Post->find('all') is used because the AppModel has the find() method and the Post model extends AppModel.

http://api.cakephp.org/class/app-model
http://book.cakephp.org/view/22/CakePHP-Conventions

Comment: The link is expired now...

Answer (score 4):

It is an [Object reference](http://mjtsai.com/blog/2004/07/15/php-5-object-references/) to the current object.

Answer (score 1):

You'll definitely want to read the [PHP documentation on classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) before diving into CakePHP

From the official reference:

> Every class definition begins with the
> keyword class, followed by a class
> name, which can be any name that isn't
> a reserved word in PHP. Followed by a
> pair of curly braces, which contains
> the definition of the classes members
> and methods. A pseudo-variable, $this
> is available when a method is called
> from within an object context. $this
> is a reference to the calling object
> (usually the object to which the
> method belongs, but can be another
> object, if the method is called
> statically from the context of a
> secondary object).

Not the most facile of definitions, but this really is stuff you're gonna have to know to navigate the code in CakePHP.