# Can I declare something global at the class level in PHP?

Tags: php, scope

Is there a way to set something as global in a class and have all methods of that class to have access to it?  Currently if I use **global $session;** I have to add it into every method that uses it even if all the methods are in the same class.

If I try to add it directly into the class then I get a php error saying it is expecting a function

```
global $session;
```

Here is a better example...

```
class test{
    function test1(){
        $self->test2($var);
    }

    function test2($var){
        return $var
    }
}
```

in this case I am getting this error below, do I need to use global or what?
**Fatal error: Call to a member function test2() on a non-object**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an error because you're using `self` instead of `this`.

i.e.

```
$this->test2($var);
```

Answer (score 3):

I may be misunderstanding the question, but I think what you want is an instance variable:

```
<?php
    class Foo {
        var $bar = "blue"

        function output() {
            echo $this->bar . "\n";
        }

        function a() {
            $this->bar = "green";
        }
        function b() {
            $this->bar = "red";
        }
    }
 ?>
```

In this case, `$bar` is the instance variable, accessible from each method.  The following code, using the Foo class:

```
$newFoo = new Foo();
$newFoo->output();
$newFoo->a();
$newFoo->output();
$newFoo->b();
$newFoo->output();
```

Would create the following output:

```
blue
green
red
```

Comment: sorry I kind of had 2 questions that got mixed together here, what I meant is lets say I have 2 methods in 1 class, I need to call method b inside of method a but I get this error when I do Fatal error: Call to a member function test2() on a non-object

Comment: Are you calling $this->test2(); ?

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways to do this,

```
<?php
class test{
    private $p_var;
    public static $s_var;

    function  test(){
        $this->p_var="RED";
        self::$s_var="S_RED";
    }

    function test1(){
        return $this->test2($this->p_var);
    }
    function test2($var){ 
        return $var;
    }
    function test3($var){ 
        $this->p_var=$var;
    }

    function stest1(){
        return $this->test2(self::$s_var);
    }
    function stest2($var){ 
        return $var;
    }
    function stest3($var){ 
        self::$s_var=$var;
    }

} 
?>
```

Heere $objtest is the object of the test() class:

```
$objtest=new test();

echo  $objtest->test1(),"<br/>"; 
$objtest->test3("GREEN"); 
echo $objtest->test1(),"<br/>";
echo "<br/>";

echo  $objtest->stest1(),"<br/>"; 
$objtest->stest3("S_GREEN"); 
echo $objtest->stest1(),"<br/>";

test::$s_var="S_BLUE";
echo $objtest->stest1();
```

Would create the following output

```
RED
GREEN

S_RED
S_GREEN
S_BLUE
```

Using static variable(test::$s_var) you can achieve what you want.
If you have any confusion about self and $this then you can read this [document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)