# $this variable in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I've just started getting familiarized with OO features of PHP, and I would like to ask you something about the `$this` variable. First of all, if a class that I'm using the `$this` keyword in does not have a defined property variable `foo`, does that mean that using the following code:

```
$this->foo = 5;
echo $this->foo;
```

will create the `foo` property on the object on runtime, like in JavaScript? What is the visibility of this property?

Comment: I would recommand to have a look on this so [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this) too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this will create the `foo` property, and its visibility will be `public` (which is the default).

You could test this quite easily:

```
<?php
class Foo {
    public function setFoo($foo) {
        $this->foo = $foo;
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->setFoo(5);
echo $f->foo;
```

Will print 5 with no errors.

Answer (score 3):

Worth mentioning is the [__get](https://www.php.net/__get) and [__set](https://www.php.net/__get) magic function. Theese methods will be called whenever an undefined property is called.

This enables a way to create pretty cool and dynamic objects. Perfect for use with webservices with unknown properties.

Comment: __construct($id) is a favorite of mine as well, allows for automatic setup of objects such as users if pulling the information from a database.  $id in this case would be passed via the class declaration (e.g. $obj = new myClass($id); )

Answer (score 1):

Yes it certainly will.

Answer (score 0):

Properties can be added to any objects, independently of its class. It is also possible to write

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->foo = 'bar';
```