# Where's the difference between self and $this-> in a PHP class or PHP method?

Tags: php, oop, this

Where's the difference between `self` and `$this->` in a PHP class or PHP method?

Example:

I've seen this code recently.

```
public static function getInstance() {

    if (!self::$instance) {
        self::$instance = new PDO("mysql:host='localhost';dbname='animals'", 'username', 'password');;
        self::$instance-> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

But I remember that `$this->` refers to the current instance (object) of a class (might also be wrong). However, what's the difference?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this

Comment: Very good source for you - http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/php-questions/php-self-vs-this/

Comment: Sad nobody told you about static:: in the answers

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`$this` refers to the instance of the class, that is correct. However, there is also something called static state, which is the same for all instances of that class. `self::` is the accessor for those attributes and functions.

Also, you cannot normally access an instance member from a static method. Meaning, you cannot do

```
static function something($x) {
  $this->that = $x;
}
```

because the static method would not know which instance you are referring to.

Comment: self:: inside an object refers to the same inheritance level properties/methods, where $this-> refers to the object inherited methods. In other words, self:: is more precise. And inside an initialized object, it is not a static call, either, unless you address an explicitly defined static properties/methods. This "answer" is wrong from top to bottom.

Comment: @AnrDaemon I don't know how old you are, but before you got your degree in hindsight, this answer was 100% correct. I don't know what PHP has done later, since I quit using it when the developers began demonstrating a blatant disregard of quality or empirical data to make their decisions. That was probably before this answer. Also this answer holds true in every other object oriented language with respect for itself. If it doesn't in PHP, then PHP is wrong, not me. Thank you for your input, it has been noted and discarded.

Comment: @TorValamo no, your answer is right. The commenter probably was confused by the usage of 'this' in JavaScript, which keeps the lookup within the current context.

Answer (score 19):

`$this` refers to the current object, `self` refers to the current class. The class is the blueprint of the object. So you define a class, but you construct objects.

So in other words, use self for static and this for non-static members or methods.

Answer (score 4):

`self` is used at the class-level scope whereas `$this` is used at the instance-level scope.

Answer (score 4):

1. this-> can't access static method or static attribute , we use self to access them.
2. $this-> when dealing with extended class will refer to the current scope that u extended , self will always refer to the parent class because its doesn't need instance to access class method or attr its access the class directly.

   ```
   <?php
   class FirstClass{
     function selfTest(){
       $this->classCheck();
       self::classCheck();
     } 
     function classCheck(){
       echo "First Class";
     }
   }
   class SecondClass extends FirstClass{
       function classCheck(){
         echo "Second Class";
       }
   }
   $var = new SecondClass();
   $var->selfTest(); //this-> will refer to Second Class , where self refer to the parent class
   ```

Answer (score 2):

`self` refers to the calling object's class. `$this` refers to the object itself.

Comment: oh that make sense! Thank you mate!

Answer (score 2):

`$this` is used to reference methods and properties of the current instance of a class.

`self` us used to reference static methods and properties, shared by all instances *(and even accessible outside of any instance)* of a class.

You can take a look at [Static Keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) *(quoting a few lines)* :

> Declaring class properties or methods
>   as static makes them accessible
>   without needing an instantiation of
>   the class. A property declared as
>   static can not be accessed with an
>   instantiated class object (though a
>   static method can)
>
> ...
>
> Static properties cannot be accessed
>   through the object using the arrow
>   operator ->.

And, from the page [Properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) *(quoting)* :

> Within class methods the properties,
>   constants, and methods may be accessed
>   by using the form `$this->property`
>   *(where `property` is the name of the property)* unless the access is to a
>   static property within the context of
>   a static class method, in which case
>   it is accessed using the form
>   `self::$property`.

Answer (score 2):

**$this** is use to call the instance of class, where **self::** is mostly used to call the constant variable within class.