# context of self

Tags: php

When I see a 'self' automatically to think of static methods. Lately I have been pointed out that self depends on the context. Just like 'parent', which can also call static methods. Consider this example:

```
error_reporting(-1);

class A
{
    public $var = 1;

    public function __construct($n)
    {
        $this->var = $n;

        self::foo();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

$obj = new A(5);
```

Operate without errors and within the method foo $ this is available.
Someone can tell me some guide that explains in detail how the calls are resolved by self and parent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948315/wheres-the-difference-between-self-and-this-in-a-php-class-or-php-method

Comment: I know the difference between self and $ this, noting that it is done in some cases self refers directly to the instance.

Comment: Maybe the second answer at this question could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this` $is a reference to the current object, while `self` is the reference to the class where it is used.

An example - the result of the code below is: `(B::func)(A::func)`.

```
class A {
    function call() {
        $this->func();
        self::func();
    }

    function func() {
        echo '(A::func)';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function func() {
        echo '(B::func)';
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->call();
```

Comment: The example is easy to understand.