# Abstract class in php calling its own static method ($this vs self)

Tags: php, static, this, abstract, self

I was wondering which keyword is correct in abstract php class, when I call its own static function.

Here's the simplified code, and I've tested both keywords - both work, but which one is technically correct?

```
<?php
abstract class B extends A{
    function a(){
        self::b("test"); //'self::' vs '$this->'
    }

    static function b($string){
        echo "test";
    }
}
?>
```

From what I understand, if the function is static it should use self within its own class to call static functions. Also the abstract means that there can be no instance of that class, so wouldn't $this be invalid, even though it worked with no warnings?

Thanks

This question is different from the possible duplicate because I use abstract classes that can't have its own instances. I understand the difference bettween self and this, but which one to use in this specific case is what I was trying to find out since both cases work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where's the difference between self and $this-> in a PHP class or PHP method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948315/wheres-the-difference-between-self-and-this-in-a-php-class-or-php-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self`, it's the same whether the class is `abstract` or not. `$this` is for an instance of the class, which is also valid for use in an `abstract` class if it has been instantiated via a concrete subclass.

Comment: Great. I am using that function b() from both within instanciated subclasses, and statically, so I guess using self:: would be the safest.