# What is a class in PHP?

Tags: php, class

I'm having serious issues understanding PHP classes from a book. They seem very difficult. What is their purpose and how do they work?

Answer (score 201, accepted):

**In a nutshell**, a Class is a blueprint for an object. And an object encapsulates conceptually related State and Responsibility of something in your Application and usually offers an programming interface with which to interact with these. This fosters code reuse and improves maintainability.

---

Imagine a Lock:

```
namespace MyExample;

class Lock
{
    private $isLocked = false;

    public function unlock()
    {
        $this->isLocked = false;
        echo 'You unlocked the Lock';
    }
    public function lock()
    {
        $this->isLocked = true;
        echo 'You locked the Lock';
    }
    public function isLocked()
    {
        return $this->isLocked;
    }
}
```

Ignore the `namespace`, `private` and `public` declaration right now.

The Lock class is a blueprint for all the Locks in your application. A Lock can either be *locked* or *unlocked*, represented by the *property* `$isLocked`. Since it can have only these two states, I use a Boolean (`true` or `false`) to indicate which state applies. I can interact with the Lock through it's *methods* `lock` and `unlock`, which will change the state accordingly. The `isLocked` method will give me the current state of the Lock. Now, when you create an object (also often referred to as an *instance*) from this blueprint, it will encapsulate unique state, e.g.

```
$aLock = new Lock; // Create object from the class blueprint
$aLock->unlock();  // You unlocked the Lock
$aLock->lock();    // You locked the Lock
```

Let's create another lock, also encapsulating it's own state

```
$anotherLock = new Lock;
$anotherLock->unlock(); // You unlocked the Lock
```

but because each object/instance encapsulates it's own state, the first lock stays locked

```
var_dump( $aLock->isLocked() );       // gives Boolean true
var_dump( $anotherLock->isLocked() ); // gives Boolean false
```

Now the entire reponsibility of keeping a Lock either locked or unlocked is encaspulated within the Lock class. You don't have to rebuilt it each time you want to lock something and if you want to change how a Lock works you can change this in the blueprint of Lock instead of all the classes *having* a Lock, e.g. a Door:

```
class Door
{
    private $lock;
    private $connectsTo;

    public function __construct(Lock $lock)
    {
        $this->lock = $lock;
        $this->connectsTo = 'bedroom';
    }
    public function open()
    {
        if($this->lock->isLocked()) {
            echo 'Cannot open Door. It is locked.';
        } else {
            echo 'You opened the Door connecting to: ', $this->connectsTo;
        }
    }
}
```

Now when you create a Door object you can assign a Lock object to it. Since the Lock object handles all the responsibility of whether something is locked or unlocked, the Door does not have to care about this. In fact any objects that can use a Lock would not have to care, for instance a Chest

```
class Chest
{
    private $lock;
    private $loot;

    public function __construct(Lock $lock)
    {
        $this->lock = $lock;
        $this->loot = 'Tons of Pieces of Eight';
    }
    public function getLoot()
    {
        if($this->lock->isLocked()) {
            echo 'Cannot get Loot. The chest is locked.';
        } else {
            echo 'You looted the chest and got:', $this->loot;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the reponsibility of the Chest is different from that of a door. A chest contains loot, while a door separates rooms. You could code the locked or unlocked state into both classes, but with a separate Lock class, you don't have to and can reuse the Lock.

```
$doorLock = new Lock;
$myDoor = new Door($doorLock);

$chestLock = new Lock;
$myChest new Chest($chestLock);
```

Chest and Door now have their unique locks. If the lock was a magical lock that can exist in multiple places at the same time, like in Quantum physics, you could assign the same lock to both chest and door, e.g.

```
$quantumLock = new Lock;
$myDoor = new Door($quantumLock);
$myChest new Chest($quantumLock);
```

and when you `unlock()` the `$quantumLock`, both Door and Chest would be unlocked.

While I admit Quantum Locks are a bad example, it illustrates the concept of sharing of objects instead of rebuilding state and responsibility all over the place. A real world example could be a database object that you pass to classes *using* the database.

Note that the examples above do not show how to get to the Lock of a Chest or a Door to use the `lock()` and `unlock()` methods. I leave this as an exercise for your to work out (or someone else to add).

Also check [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this/17027307#17027307) for a more in-depth explanation of Classes and Objects and how to work with them

For some additional resources check

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
- http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp
- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Object-Oriented-Programming-with-PHP.html
- http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/object-oriented-php

Answer (score 13):

I know you asked for a resource, not an explanation, but here's something by what I understood basic implementation of classes:

Imagine class as a template of building. A basic sketch how a building should look like. When you are going to actually build it, you change some things so it looks like your client wants (properties in case of *class*). Now you have to design how things inside of the building are going to behave (*methods*). I'm going to show it on a simple example.

**Building class:**

```
/**
 * Constructs a building.
 */
class Building
{
    private $name;
    private $height;


    public function __construct( $name, $height )
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->height = $height;
    }

    /**
     * Returns name of building.
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName( )
    {
        return $this->name;
    }


    public function elevatorUp( )
    {
        // Implementation
    }


    public function elevatorDown( )
    {
        // Implementation
    }


    public function lockDoor( )
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

**Calling the class:**

```
// Empire State Building
$empireStateBuilding = new Building( "Empire State Building", 381 );

echo $empireStateBuilding->getName( );
$empireStateBuilding->lockDoor( );


// Burj Khalifa
$burjKhalifa = new Building( "Burj Khalifa", 828 );

echo $burjKhalifa->getName( );
$burjKhalifa->lockDoor( );
```

Just copy it, run it on your localhost and try to do some changes. In case of any questions, just ask me. If you don't find this useful, just use links of previous posters, those are pretty solid tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

To offer a view from another angle if I may please (based on personal experience). You need to feel "the need of OOP" before you can actually understand what is it all about - IMHO, learning resources should come after this.

One would basically "need" to be stuck in structural difficulties when writing relatively large piece of software written in procedural style (as opposed to Object Oriented, sorry if anyone disagree with the term). By then, he/she could try restructuring the code into objects to better organize it and, naturally, learn more about OOP in detail. Again, this is my personal experience and it brought me into understanding faster than any book.

Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

Classes are the blueprints of objects.There is the name of the **Car** is class. We are define the variable and method in the class.Class is define with the curly braces.Inside the curly braces you can define the variable, method, Properties and function. Function and Method Both are the same.You can define the method and variable is the class curly braces as per your requirements.

class car{

}

foreach(**get_declared_classes()** as $class){

```
echo ($class)."<br>";
```

}

**get_declared_classes()** is an predefined function in php.It returns an array of the names of the declared classes.

[image]