# which is the best site for learning more on php

Tags: php

i am using php for a while but....... i think i need to improve on my skills ....since i have problem in troublesooting
so i am searching for a article  site which can make me comfortable working on the language.....what is the solution to develope my skills

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best site for learning PHP is the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/).

Apart from this, check out these (in no particular order)

- http://articles.sitepoint.com/category/php-tutorials
- http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp
- http://devzone.zend.com/public/view
- http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns

Also check the links given in the answers to this question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075066/what-are-good-php-and-mysql-type-blogs-to-read

And since the question is tagged CodeIgniter, check

- http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/

Comment: I was just looking at sourcemaking.com first video. Despite the presenters repetitive bumbling of his words, he brilliantly explains OOP inheritance and polymorphism in a few mintues with the diagrams on the screen. I was unable to really grasp the concept till right now.

Comment: @rrfusco Cool. I have written a short introduction to OOP here on SO if you need further resources on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/learning-php-class/2206835#2206835

Answer (score 5):

Just try hard every day... Create a code, delete it and then write it again... Repeat the task, refactor your code and don't forget to read a lot of others code... Get into their heads and your doing it right :)

Comment: I'd say keep the old code, but write another superior solution.

Answer (score 2):

Also [W3Schools](http://w3schools.com/php/php_intro.asp) is a great site to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.planet-php.net/ might be a choice for you, espacially the list of blogs concerning PHP on the right might be of interest. http://php.net's comments on the API sites are also quite educating.

Something for everyday reading: http://www.phparch.com/

Answer (score 1):

Try solving problems in PHP and, try writing code thinking how something works and how its handled by other sites.

For starters, you can start with building small multiplayer games like tic tac toe or applications like pastebin.com or making your own captcha verification etc.

Answer (score 0):

i like http://tut.php-quake.net/en/ its pretty good for beginners after that http://www.php.net doc is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it really depends at what point you are at in your learning.

At an intermediate level, I'm reading more on:

- Refactoring and code readability
- Code Structure and Design Patterns
- Learning more about OOP, Object Oriented Programming
- Better Debugging
- Profiling, performance testing and
  optimizations

Most of these topics are freely available on the net in various forums and blogs.

[Zend](http://devzone.zend.com/tutorials) has a good source of tutorials and videos on their sites. Their framework and products are expensive however.

Although the php manual is a great reference, i've always learned more by trying to accomplish simple tasks, and using other peoples tutorials as a guide.

Once you start building your basic skills, you can combine them to create larger applications.

Answer (score 0):

Well this site you're on now is really great. If you get confused about something and need help, come ask everyone here. Most users will be happy to help. But make sure not to just get them to code for you, as you'll never learn if everyone just codes for you. If they DO code for you, ask them to comment everything and explain what they've done and why.

Aside from that, http://www.tizag.com is a VERY good place to start.

:)