# Is PHP class variable definition necessary?

Tags: php, oop

Im new to PHP Object Oriented Programming but I know to code in procedural way.

If this is my PHP Class

```
<?php
class person {
  var $name;
  function __construct($persons_name) {
   $this->name = $persons_name;
  }

  function get_name() {
     return $this->name;
  }
}
?>
```

and if I access it in my PHP page

```
$jane = new person("Jane Doe");
echo "Her name is : ".$jane->get_name();
```

Question:
Is it really necessary to put the `var $name;` in my PHP class since
I can correctly get an output of ***Her name is : Jane Doe*** even without the `var $name;` in my PHP class?

Comment: *(related)* [Learning PHP Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/learning-php-class/2206835)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically, you should, as `$name` is indeed an attribute of your class. Your constructor already assigns `$persons_name` to the attribute, but if you left the `var $name;` out, the rest of your script wouldn't really know that there's such an attribute in your class. Additionally if your constructor didn't assign it right away, `person::get_name()` would attempt to retrieve an undeclared `$name` attribute and trigger a notice.

As [Brenton Alker says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287484/php-oop-programming-question/3287564#3287564), declaring your class attributes explicitly allows you to set their visibility. For instance, since you have `get_name()` as a getter for `$name`, you can set `$name` as `private` so a person's name can't be changed from outside the class after you create a `person` object.

Also, attempting to assign to undeclared class attributes causes them to be declared as `public` before being assigned.

Answer (score 4):

Not technically, no, PHP is very forgiving to things like this. But it is good practice, if only for documentation purposes.

Probably more importantly, declaring the property explicitly lets you set its [visibility](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php). In your example $name is a public property (public is the default visibility in PHP). If you don't need it to be public (it's often safer not to, due to getters/setters allowing better control over what values can be assigned) then you should declare if protected or private.

Comment: 1 more question sir:
is $this->name in the functions "related" to var $name; or they are 2 different variables

Comment: I mean the is the reason for declaring var $name is because there is $this->name inside the functions?

Comment: Yes, $this->name is referencing the ($next) property of the current instance ($this).

Answer (score 0):

it is very useful.
imagine you write a bunch of person objects with different names in an array and you will call the names of all objects at another place in your website. this is just possible when you store the name of every particular person.

Comment: Can you give a sample code where it will be very useful, since Im new to OOP. Thanks

Comment: sure:

    <?php
    function getPersons()
    {
     $sql = "SELECT name 
             FROM   person
             WHERE  something = 'somewhat'";
     
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     $persons = array();
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $persons[] = new Person($row["name"]);   
     }
     
     return $persons;
    }
    ?>

when u call this function you get the personarray. you need the stored name to identify all persons.
(i'm not really in php atm, so there may be some syntactical mistakes, but it will describe what i mean)

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you don't need to declare var $name. You can use PHP's magic methods instead, in this case [__set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) and [__get](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).

**Edit:** there's a small introduction about [magic methods](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/deciphering-magic-methods-in-php/) @ Nettuts.