# Can you give real world OOP examples in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Can you give real world OOP examples in PHP?

Comment: should be community wiki

Comment: there is no more option for community wiki anymore, is there?

Comment: @ilhan that's correct, questions have to be made CW by a moderator

Comment: Try to be a bit more specific please,...what type of examples do you want?

Comment: `class no { function __construct() { printf("THE ANSWER IS %s", "no"); }; }`

Comment: i don't know the exact benefits of oop.

Comment: @oracle certified professional, that is not real world example :(

Comment: @ilhan that is why "THE ANSWER IS no"

Comment: @oracle certified professional, please don't comment if you don't know.

Comment: @ilhan then I wouldn't be able to comment on anything

Comment: @Ilhan one of many http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/learning-php-class/2206835#2206835

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Yii framework - that's OOP, and uses MVC architecture.