# problems when extending a PHP Class

Tags: php, class, extend

I have 2 classes (2 files)

db.class.php
user.class.php

I want to use some functions from `db.class.php`:

db.class.php

```
Class DBManager {

      /** all functions goes here ...*/

}
$DB = new DBManager();
```

The content of user.class.php is:

```
Class User extends DBManager {
    function User() {

    }

    function Total($table) {
      $query = $DB->Execute("SELECT * FROM $table");
      $total = $DB->NumRows($query);
      return $total;
    }


}

$User = new User();
```

When I want to use my new function total($table) I get 2 errors:

```
Undefined variable: DB in ..\class\user.class.php on line 14
```

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function Execute() on a non-object in ..\class\user.class.php on line 14
```

I includes the 2 classes in my main.php file like:

```
include 'class/db.class.php';
include 'class/user.class.php';
```

**Edit 1:**

Related post: [best trick when using an extending class (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836504/best-trick-when-using-an-extending-class-php)

Comment: *(reference)* [Classes and Objects - Basics](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Comment: Any reason why you are not using PHP5 syntax? If you are following a tutorial there, you should get a newer one.

Comment: @Gordon: I already have my classes. I have an issue here. for what this reference?

Comment: @Mini Because apparently you're missing some basics about classes… :o)

Comment: @Gordon: How can I rewrite it in PHP5? 
@Deceze: How? Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @Mini it's for you to refresh your knowledge of how OOP in PHP5 works and to know where to look the next time. How to write classes in PHP5 is explained in the PHP Manual. I apologize if this gets across as RTFM, but I think you'll learn more reading through that OOP chapter than having me paste some code here.

Comment: You might find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/learning-php-class/2206835#2206835

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes, `$DB` is not defined/in scope within the `Total` function.
If `$DB` is a property of the class, you'll need to access it with `$this->DB`.

---

Update after update:

You're instantiating the `DBManager` into the global variable `$DB`. This variable is only in scope in the global scope. It is not automatically available in any other scope, like inside functions. Whether or not `User` inherits from `DBManager` is completely irrelevant, **the instantiated variable `$DB` is not in scope inside any function**.

There's a lazy way to access variables in the `global` scope, but I'm not going to mention that here. The proper way would be to instantiate `$DB` as a class member of `User` or pass it upon instantiating `User`:

```
class User {

    protected $DB = null;

    public function __construct($DB) {
        $this->DB = $DB;
    }

    public function Total() {
        $this->DB->…
    }
}

$DB = new DBManager();
$user = new User($DB);
```

Comment: in the db.class.php I create $DB `$DB = new DBManager();`

Comment: @Mini Are you assigning it as a property to `$this` anywhere? If not, it goes out of scope as soon as the functions returns.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to call the parent function so try somenthing like that

```
 function Total($table) {
      $query = parent::Execute("SELECT * FROM $table");
      $total = parent::NumRows($query);
      return $total;
    }
```

And if it doesnt't work try with `this` instead of `parent`

[PHP parent codumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php)

Comment: Yes I should use parent function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is that $DB? You never set that to anything, so even if you include those files, you cannot reach that variable

Depending on your db.class.php, you probably need to instantiate some sort of $DB like this

```
$DB = new db();
```

(either in the function itself, or in a constructor for the user class using `$this->DB`)

try something like this:

```
Class User extends DBManager {
    private $DB;

    function User() { // should be __construct() really
        $this->DB = new DBManager();
        $this->DB->Connect();
    }

    function Total($table) {
      $query = $this->DB->Execute("SELECT * FROM $table");
      $total = $this->DB->NumRows($query);
      return $total;
    }


}

$User = new User();
```

Comment: But you can't reach that $DB inside the memberfucntion Total. I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're confused about how inheritance works.  The sub-class inherits the public and protected members and methods of the parent class.  Therefore, in the example you've given, you should probably be using `$this->Execute("SELECT * FROM $table")` and `$this->NumRows($query)`.  Although the `Execute` and `NumRows` functions aren't defined in the `User` class, they are in the `DBManager` class, so you access them as if they were defined in `User`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my issue is:

```
$query = DBManager::Execute("SELECT * FROM $table");
$total = DBManager::NumRows($query);
```