# PHP Classes and objects

Tags: php, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/what-is-a-class-in-php)

I am a newbie to PHP. Can anyone suggest a good classes and methods tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great resource for learning OOP in PHP. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/

Answer (score 0):

The PHP manual's [Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) section is a pretty obvious/good start.

Answer (score 0):

[The manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php). Also, [PHP 101](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/638).