# php class extends, variable from other extended class

Tags: php, class

I have a main class and two extended classes:

```
class Main {
    public $foo;
}

class A extends Main {
  public function setVar()
    {
      $foo = "test"; 
    }
}

class B extends Main {
  public function getVar()
    {
      return $this->foo;
    }
}

$A = new A;
$B = new B;

$A->setVar();

echo "result: ".$B->getVar();
```

But result ($B->getVar()) stays empty. I am clearly missing something simple here... Besides that, is this the way to go splitting long classes up in relevant subclasses?

Comment: $A and $B are different __instances__ of your classes. Each is completely independent of the other... any change to $A only affects $A and not $B. And  $foo = "test";  only sets a local varaible called $foo in the setVar() method of A, not the class varaible $foo.... to do that you'd need $this->foo = "test";

Comment: ^^ That's your answer right there

Comment: *(related)* [Learning PHP classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/learning-php-class/2206835#2206835)

Comment: By the way, given the flaws in understanding some OOP principles, it may help to point out that *class* A and *instance* $A are two different kind of entities, also regarding their name (they need not to be the same at all). You could use: `$instance1 = new A; $instance2 = new B;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of using Dependency Injection (DI) to share an instance of Main between to different class instances rather than trying to use inheritence

```
class Main {
    public $foo;
}

class A {

    protected $main;

  public function setVar($data)
    {
      $this->main->foo = $data;
    }

  public function __construct(Main $main)
    {
      $this->main = $main;
    }
}

class B extends Main {
    protected $main;

  public function getVar()
    {
      return $this->main->foo;
    }

  public function __construct(Main $main)
    {
      $this->main = $main;
    }
}

$M = new Main;
$A = new A($M);
$B = new B($M);

$A->setVar("test");

echo "result: ".$B->getVar();
```

Answer (score 4):

change:

```
class A extends Main {
    public function setVar()
    {
     $foo = "test"; 
    }
}
```

to:

```
class A extends Main {
    public function setVar()
    {
     $this->foo = "test"; 
    }
}
```

Notice the **$this** keyword

Answer (score 2):

To further clarify things, it may help to think it in this way. Let's say your `Main` is a class that stands for a vehicle (and hence we rename it `Vehicle`), so *class* means that `Vehicle` defines the characteristics of a veicle but not a particular one to do operations with (we need an *instance* for that).
Let's translate also your class A in `Car` and B in `Truck`: therefore they are *specializations* of your main class that, along with possessing every characteristic of a generic `Vehicle`, extend the concept of "vehicle" and point out specific behaviours and properties of Cars in *general*, and Trucks in *general*, but - and that's the point - don't reference a *particular* car or truck. We need *instances* for that.

```
class Vehicle
{
   public $numberOfTires;
}

class Car extends Vehicle
{
    function smashMe()
    {
        echo "Oops!";
    }
}

class Truck extends Vehicle
{
    function smashMe()
    {
        echo "More Oops!";
    }
}
```

From this point we can define particular *instances* (your Porsche, my Camaro... different cars) on which we may perform operations (calling methods) and set properties.

```
$genericVehicle = new Vehicle;
$myPorsche = new Car;
$yourCamaro = new Car;
$hisTruck = new Truck;
$herTruck = new Truck;
```

But every instance remains independent from the other.

Answer (score 1):

Both are different instances of the the same class.

Operations done on one instance, does not apply on any of the others (That's kinda the point of OOP).

To do what you want,  You can have B extend A, and then perform both operations on a single instance of the B class.