# PHP Class Variable Inheritance via Class Extends

Tags: php, oop

I have two classes; `userFunction` and `userDatabase`:

```
class userDatabase {
        protected $database = 'btc.db';
        protected $short;
        protected $salt;
        function __construct(){
            $this->short = $this->salt = bin2hex(random_bytes(6));
        }
}
class userFunction extends userDatabase {
    function __construct(){
        $this->database.PHP_EOL;
        $this->short.PHP_EOL;
        $this->salt.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$r = new userFunction;
var_dump($r);
```

Output is as follows:

```
object(userFunction)#1 (3) {
  ["database":protected]=>
  string(6) "btc.db"
  ["short":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["salt":protected]=>
  NULL
}
```

This isn't exactly what I was expecting. Presumably I set `$this->short` and `$this->salt` to generate a random 6 character random hex salt from binary data. I extended the `userDatabase` class to inherit the variables to `userFunction` which I expect to be able to call via `$this->salt` and `$this->short` within `__construct()` of `userFunction`. However, the variables are returned as `NULL`.

I've been searching for an answer to why this is, but I don't seem to be able to formulate the query correctly as I'm honestly not sure what's happening here. [This seems to be a related issue, but I'm not entirely sure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11062392/php-class-extends-variable-from-other-extended-class) Specifically, is it even possible to accomplish what I'm trying to do this particular way? Is each instance of `$this->salt` and `$this->short` the same in each class, or are they both different? How would I fix my `NULL` problem, here?

I appreciate the assistance.

Comment: What is `$this->database.PHP_EOL` supposed to be doing? It's not setting any value, it's not displaying anything

Comment: at least do this  $this->short .= PHP_EOL;

Comment: `$this->database` is actually: `protected $database = 'myDatabase.db';`. So it's part of my test to ensure that I can access the variables as intended cross class, which seems to be working with this particular instance, just not with `$this->short` or `$this->salt`.

Comment: "I have two functions..." - no, you have two *classes*. It may seem picky, but learning the right terms will help you find and understand help so much easier.

Comment: @IMSop I realized the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you override `__construct` (or any other method) in a child, the parent's method doesn't get called - unless you explicitly do so.

```
class userFunction extends userDatabase {
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->database.PHP_EOL;
        $this->short.PHP_EOL;
        $this->salt.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I was going to say that .You have to call the parent constructor inside userFuction constructor.

Comment: I feel terrible about it, but adding `parent::__construct();` seems to have worked perfectly. Thanks for your time!