# Use a variable from __construct() in other methods

Tags: php, oop, constructor, global-variables

I defined a new variable in `__construct()` and I want to use it in another `function` of this `class`.
But my variable is empty in the other function!

this is my code:

```
class testObject{
     function __construct() {
           global $c;
           $data = array("name"=>$c['name'],
                         "family"=>$c['family']);
     }

     function showInfo() {
           global $data;
           print_r($data);
     }

}
```

Comment: have you actually looked at : http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php ?

Comment: Not an answer, but related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923272/use-global-variables-in-a-class/11923384#11923384

Comment: Use class properties instead of `global`:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php Using `global` is (almost?) never a good solution.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/what-is-a-class-in-php/2206835#2206835

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declare variable `$data` as global inside the constructor:

```
 function __construct() {
       global $c;
       global $data;
       $data = array("name"=>$c['name'],
                     "family"=>$c['family']);
 }
```

Then, it will be visible in other function as well.

Note that *extensive usage of global variables is strongly discouraged*, consider redesigning your class to use class variables with getters+setters.

A more proper way would be to use

```
class testObject
{
     private $data;

     function __construct(array $c) 
     {
         $this->data = array(
             "name"=>$c['name'],
             "family"=>$c['family']
         );
     }

     function showInfo() 
     {
         print_r($this->data);
     }

     // getter: if you need to access data from outside this class
     function getData() 
     {
         return $this->data;
     }
}
```

Also, consider separating data fields into separate class variables, as follows. Then you have a typical, clean data class.

```
class testObject
{
     private $name;
     private $family;

     function __construct($name, $family) 
     {
         $this->name = $name;
         $this->family = $family;
     }

     function showInfo() 
     {
         print("name: " . $this->name . ", family: " . $this->family);
     }

     // getters
     function getName() 
     {
         return $this->name;
     }

     function getFamily() 
     {
         return $this->family;
     }

}
```

And you can even construct this object with data from you global variable `$c` until you elimitate it from your code:

```
new testObject($c['name'], $c['family'])
```

Comment: @MajAfy no, it's not safe because it breaks encapsulation and makes your class depend on these variables to be defined and alterable somewhere in the global scope. It's bad practise. If the class needs $c and $data, use Dependency Injection and store these values as object properties.

Comment: @MajAfy - what do you actually mean by "safe"? Using global variables is just a bad practice and should be avoided *if possible*. I've just explained technically why the variable was empty in the other class method.

Comment: @MajAfy: I've added one more recommendation how you can redesign your class.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this way. Instead of declaring `$data` as `global` variable declare as `public` or `private` or `protected` variable inside the class depending on your use. Then set the data inside `_construct`.

Using global inside a class is not a good method. You can use class properties.

```
class testObject{
    public $data;

    function __construct() {
        global $c;
        $this->data = array("name"=>$c['name'],
                        "family"=>$c['family']);
    }

    function showInfo() {
        print_r($this->data);
    }

}
```

Comment: It dovnwoted because you need to blame OP for "bad" knowing of OOP instead of helping to understand ;)

Comment: This is exactly what I implement on my applications.