# Object oriented php class simple example

Tags: php, oop

i am beginner on php so now i try to learn object oriented i was goggling i got it some ideas but not clear concept.So i come there.Please any php guru give simple example of how to crate  classes and how to call on other php page.

**for example**

i want two classes one is `show name` and second one is `enter name`.First class show name this name come from database and second class put name in database.

**Index.php**

```
<form action="checking.php" method="post">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Please enter name">
</form>
```

Comment: you do not need two class for that all you need is two method one for adding data and other is for fetching data from database..

Comment: use setter and getter property for this.

Comment: @DipeshParmar yes you right i need one class thanks for suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a class in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/what-is-a-class-in-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way you are calling a php page is good. That is from HTML.

What I think, you are getting this wrong. A class `showName` to get name from database and `enterName` to save in database. Well what I suggest that should be a function within one single class.

```
<?php
class Name
{
    public $name;
    public function showName()
    {
        /**
        Put your database code here to extract from database.
        **/
        return($this->name);
    }
    public function enterName($TName)
    {
        $this->name = $TName;
        /**
        Put your database code here.
        **/
    }
}
?>
```

In `checking.php` you can include:

```
<?php
    include_once("name_class.php");
    $name = $_POST['name'];   //add name attribute to input tag in HTML
    $myName = new Name();
    $myName->enterName($name); //to save in database/
    $name=$myName->showName(); //to retrieve from database. 
?>
```

This way you can achieve this, this is just an overview. It is much more than that.

Comment: I think there's an error in your code. You can't put the `$` after a `$this->` because it will throw a PHP exception. See line `this->$name = $TName;`

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a class person and two methods..

```
class Person{
    public $name;
        public function showName()
        {
             echo $this->name;
        }

        public function enterName()
        {
             //insert name into database
        }
}
```

Comment: You should not "echo" from within a method. Just "return" and let the user of this class decide what he want to do with the given data.

Comment: @MischaBehrend, return is good. But this method is not getName(). For getting/setting getter/setter will be good.. Anyway thanks for your interest in this answer after two years though.