# return value of a method in php

Tags: php, class, oop, methods, return-value

I have a small problem returning value of a php method. 
in a function works like i want but when i try to create a class and the proper methods i can return the value correct.

if i use this function and call it the result is what i want:

```
function InsertData($table, array $data){
$connection = DataBaseConnection();

$row = implode(", ", array_keys($data));
$column = "'".implode("', '", array_values($data))."' ";
$sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ( $row ) VALUES ( $column )";

if($connection->query($sql) === FALSE){
    return "Error: " . $connection->error; // return the error
}else{
    return True; // return true
}}
```

i call the function this way, and works fine. retrun true if the data is insert and "ERROR + error msg" if exists an error.

```
$result = InsertData( 'table', $data_array);
```

but i want to put every stuf of the data base in a class, and the class have the proper methods. i am a new developer in php oop, and i have a problem. I can return the same values of my previous function in my correspondent method of the class

```
    class dba{ 
        public function conn{ 
             /*some code*/ return $conn; //
}
        public function DBA_Insert($table, array $data) {

        $conn = $this->Conn() ;

        $row = implode(", ", array_keys($data));

        $column = "'".implode("', '", array_values($data))."' ";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} ( $row ) VALUES ( $column )";

        if($conn->query($sql) === FALSE){
            return "Error: " . $conn->error;
```

> // this return an object and i want to retrun the string ERROR + Error
>   msg like in my function

```
        }else{
            return true;
```

> // don't return nothing but the data is insert in the data base, and i wan´t to return true to use in the other side of the aplication

```
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
```

to call the class and the method this way:

```
$insertMsg = new dba();
$insertMsg->DBA_Insert( 'messages', $data);
```

if you can help me i apreciate.
thanks for your time ;)

`

Comment: What exactly is the question? $connection->query($sql) <<< $connection is undefined. You are wide open to sql injection.

Comment: $connection is the conn. sorry for the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object oriented php class simple example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20603992/object-oriented-php-class-simple-example)

Comment: the problem I have is the returned values are not the same as in my function. in function i return the message and true. in my method return an object and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you call `DBA_Insert` method shows that you don't assign returned value.
`$insertMsg` is just object instance  (variable that holds a pointer/link) of `dba` class and you call one of its methods. With proper names your code should like this:

```
$dba = new dba();
$result = $dba->insert(...);
```

I've changed method name as well, because it will always belong to objects of dba class and your instance variable name should also be self explanatory.

Comment: _Thanks for your response_. resolve my problem, and thanks for the explanation of my problem, and the reason for rename the method.. **many thanks**