# PHP how to call/save a public variable in a class

Tags: php, class, oop

I have this example:

```
    class test_names {
        public name = 'ralph';

        function dispname() {
            return $this->name;
        }
    }

$test = new test_names;
$test->name = 'John';
$test->dispname;
```

now the result will be "John" because I saved that in de public var

Now I have another file called test2.php and I do this:

```
    $test = new test_names;
    $test->dispname;
```

the result will be "ralph"
but I don't want that, I want it to be "John" (that value I've set before)

How can I make this happen?

Comment: What's the relationship between the two php files?

Comment: Use a static variable `name`.

Comment: Oh sorry, first file is called class.test_names.php, I put the class in here. Then I have a file called test1.php there I call the class and set the name to "john". And I have another file called test2.php: There I call the class and just display the name, and I want that to be "John" as I defined that in test1.php

Comment: Are you executing test1.php and test2.php in the same hit? Otherwise you need a session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont instanciate the class again as you already did it:

replace

```
   $test = new test_names;
   $test->dispname;
```

by

```
$test->dispname;
```

Comment: Yes I know, but I instanciate the class in test1.php and now I want to use the same clas also in test2.php so I do need to instanciate it in test2.php again right?

Comment: There is a difference between classes and the objects your create from it (instances). When you `new Class` something you get an instance of that class. All the non-static properties are only for that instance. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/what-is-a-class-in-php/2206835#2206835