# PHP calling class from another class

Tags: php, class

I want to call a PHP class in another class and get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function quote() on a non-object
```

Class 1:

```
class logmein {

    //Connect DB
    function dbconnect(){
        require_once('class.MySQL.php');
        $db = new Db();    

    }

    //login function
    function login($username, $password){

        //conect to DB
        $this->dbconnect(); 

        // Quote and escape form submitted values
        $name = $db -> quote($username);                    //throwing error
        $email = $db -> quote($password);                   //throwing error

    }
}
```

Class 2:

```
class DB {

    public function quote($value) {
        $connection = $this -> connect();
        return "'" . $connection -> real_escape_string($value) . "'";
    }
}
```

I call it:

```
$log = new logmein();
$log->login('James Bond', '007');
```

What I have to do to call them into each other? Or is there a other way to do that. Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a class in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206387/what-is-a-class-in-php)

Comment: looks to me that $db is not visible outside of logmein::dbconnect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$db` object falls out of scope from `dbconnect()` to `login()`. Set it as a class property instead so you can access it anywhere in your class:

```
class logmein {

    protected $db; // property available to this class and child classes

    //Connect DB
    function dbconnect(){
        require_once('class.MySQL.php');
        $this->db = new Db(); // say "$this" to refer to it

    }

    //login function
    function login($username, $password){

        //conect to DB
        $this->dbconnect(); 

        // Quote and escape form submitted values
        $name = $this->db->quote($username); // works now
        $email = $this->db->quote($password); // works now

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure that the DB is accessible across your class functions, so it needs to be stored in a class property.

```
class logmein {
    private $db; //store the database object

    //Connect DB
    function dbconnect(){
        require_once('class.MySQL.php');
        $this->db = new Db();    

    }

    //login function
    function login($username, $password){

        //conect to DB
        $this->dbconnect(); 

        // Quote and escape form submitted values
        $name = $this->db->quote($username);
        $email = $this->db->quote($password);

    }
}
```

That being said, this setup is tightly coupling your database with the login. Consider looking into 'dependency injection' and other ways to keep your code components separate.