# Structure of Singleton

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

I have the following four PHP files:

*1. Singleton.php*

```
<?php

class Singleton {
    private static $instance = null;

    protected function __clone() {}
    private function __construct() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self;
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
}

?>
```

*2. Debugger.php*

```
<?php

interface Debugger {
    public function debug($message);
}

?>
```

*3. DebuggerEcho.php*

```
<?php
require_once 'Singleton.php';
require_once 'Debugger.php';

class DebuggerEcho extends Singleton implements Debugger {
    public function debug($message) {
        echo $message . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

?>
```

*4. TestSingleton.php*

```
<?php
require_once 'DebuggerEcho.php';

$debugger = DebuggerEcho::getInstance();
$debugger->debug('Hello world');

?>
```

Problem is, when I call line `$debugger->debug('Hello world')`. I want to keep this structure but avoid this (classical) message:

```
Call to undefined method Singleton::debug() in TestSingleton.php.
```

What is going wrong? Thank you for help.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2085988/212940) should provide some interesting reading for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `new self` creates an object of the class where it's contained; here `Singleton`. To create an object of the class you use for the call you can use `new static` instead (assuming you are using PHP 5.3 or later):

```
public static function getInstance() {
    if (self::$instance === null) {
        self::$instance = new static;
    }
    return self::$instance;
}
```

See also: [What does new self(); mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396415/what-does-new-self-mean-in-php)

Not that this implementation of `Singleton` is not really reusable because it supports only one instance. For example you couldn't use this `Singleton` class as a base class for both database connections and loggers: it can only hold one or the other.

Comment: This works like a charm - fix it, but we must use - new static. Older version of PHP (x < 5.3) would not be able to solve this problem, so?

Comment: For older versions of PHP 5 there's a workaround using `ReflectionClass`, you can find it in comments here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: We can summarize that the problem is in the Late Static Bindings. Thank you again for clear answers.