# Singleton pattern not working in PHP 5.2

Tags: php, singleton, php-5.2

I have this simple singleton class:

```
public static function getInstance() {                
    if (!self::$_controller) {
        self::$_controller = new self();
    }

    return self::$_controller;
}
```

Using PHP 5.3, this code seems to work fine, but on PHP 5.2 it seems like the instance is not returned. I put in a simple debug message like so:

```
public static function getInstance() {                
    if (!self::$_controller) {
        self::$_controller = new self();
        echo "I seem to be working";
    }

    return self::$_controller;
}
```

But "I seem to be working" is never echoed out. What's going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: `var_dump(self::$_controller)` before the `if`?

Comment: What did you mean with self::$_controller = new self();
Is your class name "self"?

Comment: @dbh: Would you please mind to paste the entire code of the class file?

Comment: Regarding self: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2396415/what-does-new-self-mean-in-php

Comment: @minitech - Results from var_dump(self::$_controller) returned NULL as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is working at my end for PHP 5.3 and 5.2 both.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('log_errors', 0);

class SingleTon {
        private static $_controller = null;

        private function __construct() {
                // do something here or leave it blank.
        }

        public static function getInstance() {
                if (!self::$_controller) {
                        self::$_controller = new self();
                        echo "I seem to be working";
                }

                return self::$_controller;
        }
}

$obj = SingleTon::getInstance();
echo "\n";
```

?>

It displays "I seem to be working". Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: My problem was somewhere completely different, but this does work. thanks.