# How to add a public var in class in php?

Tags: php, class

I currently have a error-system like this on my header.php:

```
include('class.error.php');
Errsys::disable_default();
Errsys::enable_logging('errors.dat');
```

So, I'm not creating a new object via `$asd = new Errsys;`. How to add a variable to class, so it can be called like `Errsys::variable` or via any similar syntax inside or outside the class?

Hope you understood.

Martti Laine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of php are you using? You can add a class variable like:

```
class className {
  public $varname;
  ............ more code
```

In static context:

```
class className {
  public static $varname;
  ............ more code
```

Comment: PHP5. I can add variable that way, but then I can't call it like `$this->variable` if I don't create the object like this: `$asd = new Errsys;` Any other ways to call it?

Comment: you call with with self http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this

Answer (score 1):

You can create a static variable similar to creating a static function:

```
public static $whatever;
```

I would recommend reading PHP manual's section on [classes and objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for further information.

ps. If your class is called Errsys, I'd recommend calling the file class.errsys.php as well instead of class.error.php :)