# PHP Checking variables isset, empty, defined etc

Tags: php

i was looking at a tutorial from [ZendCasts](http://www.zendcasts.com/painless-html-emails-with-zend_mail/2010/06/) where i wondered about the code he used. a simplified version below

```
class TestClass {
    private $_var;
    private static function getDefaultView() {
        if (self::$_var === null) { ... } // this is the line in question
    }
}
```

i wonder why is something like `isset(self::$_var)` not used instead?
when i use `self::` i need the `$` sign to refer to variables? i cant do `self::_var`?
how does `==` differ from `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are several questions.

> I wonder why is something like isset(self::$_var) not used instead

It's indifferent. The advantage of using `isset` is that a notice is not emitted if the variable ins't defined. In that case, `self::$_var` is always defined because it's a declared (non-dynamic) property. `isset` also returns false if the variable is `null`.

> when i use self:: i need the $ sign to refer to variables?

Note that this is not a regular variable, it's a class property (hence the `self`, which refers to the class of the method). Yes, except if this is a constant. E.g.:

```
class TestClass {
    const VAR;
    private static function foo() {
        echo self::VAR;
    }
}
```

> how does == differ from ===

This has been asked multiple times in this site alone.

Answer (score 1):

1. For the == and === operators, see [the manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php).
2. For the self, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator means "equal and of same type", so no automatic type casting happens. Like `0 == "0"` is true, however `0 === "0"` is not.

The `self::$var` syntax is just the syntax. use $ to refer to a variable, no $ to refer to a function.

The `self::` syntax is used for static access (class variables, class methods, vs. instance variables refereed to by `this`).