# PHP Equivalent to Ruby's @instance_variable?

Tags: php, ruby, this, instance-variables

I was wondering if there is a shorter, better or cleaner way to assign and use class variables in PHP, then through `$this->instance_variable` ?

```
class Bar {
  #  internal variables
  var $foo = "Hello World";

  public function foo() {
    return $this->foo;
  }
}
```

I am not very familiar with all PHP's variable scoping, but from what I understood at the official docs, you can either define them global, or access them trough `$this->`?
Is there a keyword to define them as instance variable, so they are accessible like [Rubys @variable](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope#Ruby_Instance_Variables)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a few key assumptions your'e bringing from ruby that don't translate well into PHP.

The correct way to declare and use object properties (equivalent to Ruby's instance variables) in PHP is

```
class Foo
{
    //accesible from inside this objects of this class, 
    //objects that have this class as an ancestor, and from
    //outside the object  
    //var $bar; is equivalent.  "var" is PHP 4 syntax, 
    //when everything was public
    public $bar;

    //accesible from inside this objects of this class, 
    //objects that have this class as an ancestor  
    protected $baz;

    //accesible from inside this objects only
    private $fiz;

    protected function example()
    {
        echo $this->bar . "\n";
        echo $this->baz . "\n";
        echo $this->fiz . "\n";
    }
}
```

PHP's OO syntax is based on the Java/C# view of the world.  However, because every PHP page/script/program starts off in the global score, the `$this` pseudo reference to the local object is needed.  Without it, you'd create a large degree of ambiguity around situations like this

```
//In main.php
$foo = "bar";
include('example.php');

//in example.php
class Example
{
    public $foo="baz";
    public function scopeIsHardLetsGoShopping()
    {
        global $foo;
        echo $foo;
    }
}
```

So, in the method should the $foo referenced be the object variable, or the global variable? If you say it should be the object variable, how do you access the global foo from a method?  If you say it should be the global variable how do you access the local property after declaring a variable with the same name global?

Ruby and python gave scoping some thoughts at the onset of the language, so these problems can be avoided.  PHP started as a quick way to hack in some c-code to process forms and output HTML.  Because PHP makes reasonable efforts to be backwards compatible, you end up with quirky work arounds like $this.

Coming form Ruby it seems a little verbose, but it's a fundamental part of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

PHP instance properties are accessed via the `$this->variable` operator internally, and public properties as `$object->property`.

You can access a class variable internally via `self::$variable`, which is similar to Ruby's class variables. [Discussion of self:: vs. $this-> in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

In general, you will find PHP much more verbose than Ruby, not least in terms of characters required to reference a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an instance variable (like your `$foo`) the only way to access it is through `$this->foo`.

You could, if desperate, write something like `$foo =& $this->foo;` so you have a local reference to the same variable, but the only benefit is saving a few characters at the cost of added confusion.