# PHP: This and Self

Tags: php, static, self

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: self vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this) and
>   [When to use self over $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-over-this)

What's the difference between `$this` and `self::`

example:

```
class Object{
   public $property;
   function doSomething(){
        // This
        $something = $this->property;
        // Self
        $something = self::property;
        ...code...
   }
}
```

Comment: exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this` refers to the *instance* of the object, while `self` returns to the class itself. When using static calls, you refer to `self` because you are not-required to have an instance of a class (i.e. `$this`).

Answer (score 2):

`$this` references the object, in which the code appears, `self` is the class. You call "usual" methods and properties with `$this` from within any method and you call static methods and properties with `self`

```
class A {
    public static $staticVar = 'abc';
    public $var = 'xyz';
    public function doSomething () {
        echo self::$staticVar;
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
```

Your "Self"-example is invalid anyway.

Comment: Be careful with `self`. `self` refers to the most recent class in the chain which contains that method. If you have a static `$name` property in both a `ParentClass` and `ChildClass` which hold "Parent" and "Child" respectively, but `showName`, which uses `self::$name`, only exists in `ParentClass` then `$child->showName()` will return `Parent` not `Child`.

Comment: Usually its the prefered behaviour, when `self` really means "the class itself" and not any subclass. Use "Late Static Binding (`static`), which always refers to the called class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from here

Link: http://www.phpbuilder.com/board/showthread.php?t=10354489:

> Use $this to refer to the current
>   object. Use self to refer to the
>   current class. In other words, use
>   $this->member for non-static members,
>   use self::$member for static members.

Answered by John Millikin [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this/151976#151976)