# What is $this->?

Tags: php

What I think I know so far:

so `$this->` is to access a function/var outside its own function/var ?

but how does `$this->` know if its a function or a variable ?

why we refer to a var like this `$this->data` instead of this `$this->$data` ?

Comment: "The pseudo-variable $this is available when a method is called from within an object context. $this is a reference to the calling object (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another object, if the method is called statically from the context of a secondary object). " http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: I wonder if such question has been never asked here on SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: self vs. $this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$this` refers to the current object that a method has been invoked on. It knows if it's a function if there is a pair of parentheses at the end. We use the former syntax because `$this->$data` means look at the field whose name is `$data`; e.g. `$this->foo` if `$data == 'foo'`

Comment: I think "whose name is stored in `$data`" would make more sense here.

Answer (score 3):

`$this` is the variable referring to the object that you are currently inside. `$this->` will access either a method or field in the current object.

As for why is it `$this->data` and not `$this->$data`, that's just a syntax quirk. You'd have to ask the PHP language designers. It's probably because the latter wouldn't make much sense for a method.

If this looks like Greek to you, then you may want to head over to [the PHP manual's section on classes and objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) and read up.

Comment: Either "an object" or "instance of a class". If you want to talk about the class itself, you use `self::`.

Comment: Or better yet: '[...] the instance of the class [...]'

Comment: @NSanjay are you familiar with object-oriented programming?

Comment: @NSanjay I find that hard to believe. You've never referred to other methods/fields in a class?

Comment: ya that's why my first coding was messy until someone pointed it out to me by rewriting it using $this->, & that's how I came to ask this question. So my first post is correct ?

Answer (score 1):

`$this` represents the instance of a given object, from the context of within the object.

I would say, knowing whether you're accessing a method or property is your responsibility. Read documentation. If you're calling an object method using this, it uses the expected syntax of `$this->method($args);` and properties (member variables) use the expected syntax of `$this->var = 'value';`

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty long subject, but in sort, $this is a pointer to an instance. $this->data refers to the data variable of a particular instance(this instance). It is $this->data and not $this->$data just because of convention.

Comment: so its just a security thing ?

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with security, take a look at object oriented programming.

Comment: it's a way to refer to the particular object. You'd have to take a look at classes and oop to understand more.

Comment: using $this-> we can nest function within functions ?
wont this complicate the reader ?
as in the person who want to modify the code later on