# what is the function of self keyword in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: self vs. $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

it is from php manual, please let me know where and why i use self keyword

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public static $my_static = 'foo';

    public function staticValue() {
        return self::$my_static;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
    public function fooStatic() {
        return parent::$my_static;
    }
}


print Foo::$my_static . "\n";

$foo = new Foo();
print $foo->staticValue() . "\n";
print $foo->my_static . "\n";      // Undefined "Property" my_static 

print $foo::$my_static . "\n";
$classname = 'Foo';
print $classname::$my_static . "\n"; // As of PHP 5.3.0

print Bar::$my_static . "\n";
$bar = new Bar();
print $bar->fooStatic() . "\n";
?>
```

Comment: my_static is a static var. you can access it from outside the class via `<CLASSNAME>::$my_static` (`FOO::$my_static`) to access it from within the class you use `self`. `self` is basicly the same as `$this`, but `$this` only works if you initiate the class (`new FOO()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

self allows you to refer to class in which you currently are; it's like $this, but not about instance, but allows you to call static methods without naming the class (parent works in a similar manner, but points to parent class, not self class - self-explanatory, I think).

Answer (score 2):

self is used to access class methods and variables (static ones) while $this is for accessing object instance variables and methods.