# Call variable inside class from function inside class without $this

Tags: php, class

I recently needed to change my function to static and now $this does not work, and i need to get variable in the same class is there way to do it without $this?

Comment: Do you actually have a valid reason for making your method static?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/151976/71904 should help clarify

Answer (score 1):

Static functions, by definition, are never called on an instantiated object, so `$this` is meaningless in that context (doesn't point to the current object).

Comment: You can also access static properties. Also, you shouldn't be calling the static method by the `->` operator.

Comment: -1 You are not helping OP with this answer. It's confusing because your use of a static method is simply not correct.

Comment: I'm sorry ,I was too lazy. And I hate to use these little comment boxes to illustrate what I mean. But here goes: You are partially right about static methods (is what they are called) not 'belonging' on an instantiated object; they do belong in their class definitions, but they shouldn't be called on instantiated object, is what you probably meant. But then afterwards you go ahead and instantiate the class and call the static method on it anyhow! I mean how much more confusing does it get?

Comment: @fireeyedboy That was a mistake on my behalf and it was edited a while before you left your comment.

Comment: I saw that, and if you left it there I'd be tempted to remove the -1. But the other part I was talking about is still a bit confusing. Static methods belong perfectly well on instantiated objects (or at least in their class definitions) but shouldn't be called in an instantiated context. Perhaps that is what you meant, but now it's a bit confusing the way you phrased it.

Comment: Removed -1 and upvoted +1. It's even better phrased now than I phrased it in my last comment. Not called "on" an instantiated object is better, yes. Because "in" an instantiated object you can perfectly well call a static method with `self::staticMethod()`. Now I was the one who was being confusing. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Prefix it with:

```
self::$VariableName
```

or

```
MyClassName::$VariableName
```

(For more info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: That's only going to work if `$VariableName` is itself a static property

Comment: Of course. I assumed that the OP knew how `static` worked, since they're using it, but that's also why I linked the doc page.

Comment: Its somehow dont work it looks like       
var $_tpl_vars = array();

$this->_tpl_vars[$tpl_var] = $value;

when i try self it complain about bracket (syntax error, unexpected '[')

Comment: Please show some more code Poemn (edit your question) so people can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: actually it works now except i fixed it to be 
' public static $_tpl_vars             = array();' but now other function does not work, why it used to be var _tpl_vars without $?

Comment: @Poemm Please explain (in your question, not here), why you *needed* to make the method static?

Answer (score 0):

In a static class, you could access it by `self::`