# PHP: Object assignment to static property, is it illegal?

Tags: php, oop

Is it illegal to assign some object to static property?

I am getting HTTP 500 error in below code.

```
require_once('class.linkedlist.php');

class SinglyLinkedlistTester {
    public static $ll = new Linklist();
}
```

HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfil the request.

Note: No issue with non object like string,int assignment to static variable.
As an example,

```
public static $ll = 5; //no issue
```

Also there is no code issue in class.linkedlist.php.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't create new objects in class property declarations.  You have to use the constructor to do this:

```
class SinglyLinkedlistTester {
    public static $ll;

    public function __construct() {
        static::$ll = new Linklist();
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Also, you can test your files for errors without executing them using PHP's lint flag (`-l`):

```
php -l your_file.php
```

This will tell you whether there are syntax or parsing errors in your file (in this case, it was a parse error).

Comment: @Josh:  Actually, [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) is probably more helpful.

Comment: @drrcknlsn, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this I guess either would work in this case, but self would probably be better as the property is static, and using `$this` in a static method with an object being instanciated could cause problems.

Comment: @drrcknlsn Definitely helpful. I was referring to this specifically, *"Like any other PHP static variable, static properties may only be initialized using a literal or constant; expressions are not allowed. So while you may initialize a static property to an integer or array (for instance), you may not initialize it to another variable, to a function return value, or to **an object**."* Seems appropriate for what he was attempting to do.

Comment: @ All, anything to do with late static binding in my case? late static binding is related to inheritance and context of resolution.

Comment: @Walkerneo: I did not use `$this`, I used `static`, and I used it intentionally.  Reversed your edit.  Please see my comment to @Josh for a link describing late static binding.

Comment: @drrcknlsn, i didn't understand use of constructor, suppose i want SinglyLinkedlist::some_static_method(). I am not instantiating any object in this case, so how come static property will be initialized without constructor call? let's assume i am using $ll inside some_static_method().

Comment: @Praveen: If your class is not meant to be instantiated, then `__construct()` will obviously not work.  You'll have to initialize `$ll` with some static method (eg. `SinglyLinkedlistTester::init()` or similar).

Comment: @drrcknlsn, oops, my mistake. I thought it was a typo, I'd never seen the static variable before.

Comment: @drrcknlsn, but if a class is static itself then constructor your solution above will not work, correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Shouvik: I answered that question already in previous comments.

Answer (score 5):

you should take care, that you don't override the static property on each instantiation of a object, therefore do:

```
class SinglyLinkedlistTester {
    private static $ll;

    public function __construct() {
        if (!self::$ll) self::$ll = new Linklist();
    }
}
```