# Expression not allowed - set class var with new object

Tags: php, oop, object

I tried to do following stuff:

```
class Foo {
    private $bar = new baz(); // Expression is not allowed as field default value
}

class Baz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

I cant find any results why the expression should not be allowed. Why can i assign string, integer and other data types but no objects?

Comment: You can't call a class from inside a class you either need to extend `Baz` or pass `Baz` through `Foo`s construct to use `Baz` as a variable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009276/php-object-assignment-to-static-property-is-it-illegal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its just the way PHP works. You can't use functions (including constructors) in class properties.

> The properties are a blueprint and must be independent of the runtime
>   environment ([source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php))

You can assign objects to the properties via the `__construct()`

```
class Foo {
    private $bar;

    public function __construct() {
         $this->bar = new baz();
    }
}

class Baz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

```
<?php
class Baz {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
class Foo {
  private $bar;
  function __construct(){
    $bar = new Baz(); // Expression is not allowed as field default value
  }

}
?>
```