# Is there any reason to use the self keyword?

Tags: php

With the new static keyword in PHP 5, is there any reason to use self keyword? I don't see any use-cases for it anymore

Comment: Well, actually there's a difference - have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this#answer-6807615

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self` and `static` mean two different things. See the documentation on [late static binding](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). The first two examples demonstrate the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of static method if you wish to call another static method - you use `self::anotherStaticMethod()`

Answer (score 0):

It is for `static` class members (access staic things in the same class) - that do not have a `$this`.