# Any <good> reason or use case to use the self keyword in php instead of static keyword?

Tags: php, oop

As of php 5.3, the `static` keyword resolved the late static binding issue and it can be used like most other OO languages use `self`.  In PHP `self` still exists.

I know how the two keywords are separate functionally as previously pointed out in this question: [Is there any reason to use the self keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9457550/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-self-keyword).

However, my question is: Can anyone give a reason why you would want to use `self` in code meant to run only with 5.3 or later PHP?  Does `self` have better performance?  I've yet to find any compelling use case for using the `self` keyword anymore.  My understanding is it only remains to allow old libraries to continue working in an expected manner.

The key to the question is can anyone suggest a good reason, ANY GOOD REASON, just one, tiny, little, reason that makes sense for a competent PHP developer to say "Gee, here I should really use 'self' instead of 'static'."

Because you might want to shoot yourself in the foot and that's a reason to use it isn't a good reason.

Comment: Does `self` have better performance than what?

Comment: You've stated that you know they both do different things - those different things *are* why you might use one or the other. `self` will only return it's own class's static method/var even if it's been extended, where as `static` will return the extended method/var instead (if it has indeed been extended).

Comment: @BenGriffiths  If I extend a class and override a non-final method or property, when I access it in a child class it should use my overridden items.  I agree if someone believes they need to break fundamental this basic OOP principle, using `self` in this manner does provide a 'reason'. Still, that use case not a good reason, in fact it makes me wish it didn't exist at all--many noobs are still using self without understanding the unintended limits they're locking themselves into down the road.

Comment: @sixeightzero Since self is evaluated at op code generation time, not runtime it might take less time to evaluate self vs. static.  I don't know if it does or doesn't, hence the question on stack overflow.

Comment: It's true it's scope for reasonable use is very limited with the latest versions of PHP, and other than what we've discussed I doubt there's any other reason to touch it. Being as it does provide a different purpose to static though I can see why it still exists (not just from a legacy standpoint).

Comment: I don't understand why people talk about the performance of microoptimizations in PHP - the language is one of the slowest in common use.  1% faster (or 10% on a completely contrived benchmark) than a slug is still a slug.

Comment: @SeanMcSomething If you don't understand something you probably shouldn't comment on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah! Found my one good reason.  At the moment in php 5.3  you cannot access compile time constants with `static`.

The code below will throw an error

```
 class Foo{
      const BAR = "FREE BEER";

      public static function whatDoWeLove(){
          return static::BAR;
      }
 }


 echo Foo::whatDoWeLove();
```

The error I get is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  "static::" is not allowed in compile-time constants in....
```

So, I guess for now  `self` limps along until that changes or PHP adds the ability to use the `final` keyword with static properties.  Drats.

Comment: Ha. That seems to qualify more as a bug than a "<good> reason".