# Calling a function from within another function in PHP, but get error Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php

I have the code below: from the getData function im trying to call **get_xml** within the same class, but I get the error `Using $this when not in object context` . I have been programming quite some time, so maybe my brains shut off, but imho this should work right? What am I missing here?

```
class modDataHelper {

    function getData($rid) {
        $xml = $this->get_xml('http://www.dataserver.nl/rss/feed.php?id=' . $rid, 60000);

        return $xml;
    }

    function get_xml($url, $max_age) {
        $file = 'cache/' . md5($url);

        if (file_exists($file)
                && filemtime($file) >= time() - $max_age) {
            // the cache file exists and is fresh enough
            return simplexml_load_file($file);
        }

        $xml = file_get_contents($url);
        file_put_contents($file, $xml);
        return simplexml_load_string($xml);
    }

}
```

In another file I call

```
$data = modDataHelper::getData(19464);
```

Comment: fixed it by calling `$xml = self::get_xml('http://www.dataserver.nl/rss/feed.php?id=' . $rid, 60000);` Thanks guys for helping me understand AND give me the answer!

Comment: Its calling statically using scope resolution operator "::" rather than "->" and self keyword stands for "calling classes own function hence 'self'"

Comment: Not for the points, but i think the Q&A could use some upvotes, because google is not really spitting out clear answers, at least not as clear as yours!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling a static method by using `::`.

There is no $this in static context use `self`.

[When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

```
class modDataHelper {

    static function getData($rid) {
        $xml = self::get_xml('http://www.dataserver.nl/rss/feed.php?id=' . $rid, 60000);

        return $xml;
    }

    static function get_xml($url, $max_age) {
        $file = 'cache/' . md5($url);

        if (file_exists($file)
                && filemtime($file) >= time() - $max_age) {
            // the cache file exists and is fresh enough
            return simplexml_load_file($file);
        }

        $xml = file_get_contents($url);
        file_put_contents($file, $xml);
        return simplexml_load_string($xml);
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't think PHP even allowed calling a non-static method statically anymore without at the very least throwing a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Ghommey's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9820664/679733) or...

```
$mdh = new modDataHelper;
$data = $mdh->getData(19464);
```

Also take a look of this

- [Visibility of a properties or methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)
- [Scope Resolution Operator **(::)**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)
- [**Static** Keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: I thought of this, but that kinda felt dirty from inside a function of the same class...

Comment: From inside function of the same class, you can use `$data = $this->getData(19464);` where `$this` refers to current object and `getData()` to object's method.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now, you refered to my last line of code, not to the getData func. Tata

Comment: In fact, `$xml = $this->get_xml(...` is OK but in this case you can't call `getData` method as static, using **(::)** operator.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling getData statically, i.e. there is no object instance, no this.

You need to do something like:

```
$data = new modDataHelper();
$data->getData(10464)
```

Or if you want to use static methods you need to declare them as "static" and use "self::", instead of "$this->".

For more info see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).