# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context on Database instance

Tags: php, class, sqlite

i have these in Database.php

```
class Database
{
    private $dbname = 'auth';
    private $db_instance;   

    public function __construct($q)
    {
        if(!$this->db_instance)
        $this->db_instance = new SQLite3($q);
    }

    private function init()
    {
        if(!$this->db_instance)
        {
            $this->db_instance = new SQLite3($dbname);
        }
    }

    private function close()
    {
        if($this->db_instance)
        $this->db_instance->close();
    }

    static public function fetch_a_row($q)
    {
        $this->init();
        $res = $this->db_instance->query(SQLite3::escapeString($q));
        $ret = $res->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC); 
        $this->close();

        return $ret;
    }

    static public function exec($q)
    {
        $this->init();
        $this->db_instance->exec(SQLite3::escapeString($q));
        $this->close();
    }


}
```

in try to call him on index.php

```
<?php
require_once('Database.php');

$ret = Database::fetch_a_row('SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname = "test"');

echo $ret['id'];
?>
```

but response :

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in /www/cgi-bin/auth/Database.php on line 29
```

is there anyone could help ? 
thank in advance

Comment: Friendly advice: If this class is not purely for educational purposes just drop it and use slightly more advanced, existing classes/frameworks. If it is for educational purposes only, drop it anyway and start by studying other database libraries ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your static method, you are using the instance accessor `$this->` which is not valid syntax. Typically, you would need to use `self::`, but it isn't as simple as that. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this), it should explain the difference between using `self` (when in static methods) and `$this` (when in non-static methods).

From a glance at the code though, the `Database` class requires you to instantiate the object in order to create the DB instance utilised later on. For this reason, it would make more sense to make your query methods `fetch_a_row` and `exec` non-static, and change your code to instantiate the object and use that instance.

However, this is all stuff that you must figure out as the `Database` class needs a bit of refactoring in order to work. The first thing to ask yourself would be "why are you utilising static methods?" - if you don't need them, it may be simpler to use non-statics (as mentioned above). From there, I guess it's up to you the direction you take.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$this` in a static function, for which there is no context (because static refers to the class whereas `$this` looks for the current object). Try `self` in your class' `fetch_a_row` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this` in static context. Remove static from the function and call it like this:

```
$db = new Database();
$ret = $db->fetch_a_row('SELECT * FROM user WHERE uname = "test"');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create an instance of the database class.

```
$db = new Datatbase('test');
```

Now you have object where you can use

```
$results= $db->fetch_a_row(query);
```