# Is there a shortcut syntax for accessing object methods from within an object scope in PHP?

Tags: php, methods

I'm just asking based on experience with other languages that can disambiguate method calls from global function calls based on class scope - eg:

```
class Foo {
 function bar(){
   echo 'bletch';
 }

 function baz(){
   $this->bar();
 }
}
```

So I guess I'm asking whether there's another way of doing `$this->bar()`, or in other words, how can I leave out `$this`, which just seems redundant given the context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't access `bar()` from within `baz()` without `$this->` in PHP as you can easily have global function `bar()` that is not part of any class/object (which is the difference then most of those languages you are reffering to), which would result in collision.

Comment: One could use `self::` instead of `$this->`, as stated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this

Comment: `self::` operator is accessing the class itself (static methods, properties and constants that belong to the class), while `$this->` is accessing the instance (instance methods and properties like in the case of the question).

Comment: Thanks, just checking. Other languages can disambiguate from global scope functions based on the class scope (favoring whichever method / function has the tightest scope). I wonder whether formal namespacing could help here, but frankly it's probably not worth the headache either way. Just checking in case there was a trick I had missed along the way.

Answer (score 0):

In short it is not posible.

because calling `bar` would call a function named `bar` outside the class given the following:

```
function bar() {
 echo 'foo';
}

class Foo {
 function bar(){
   echo 'bletch';
 }

 function baz(){
   $this->bar();
 }

 function foobar() {
   bar();
 }
}

$instance = new Foo();

$instance->foobar();
```

this would echo `foo` of the `function bar()` instead of `bletch` of the `method bar()`