# Using "this" and "self" in PHP

Tags: php

> Use $this to refer to the current object. Use self to refer to the
>   current class. In other words, use $this->member for non-static
>   members, use self::$member for static members.

http://board.phpbuilder.com/showthread.php?10354489-RESOLVED-php-class-quot-this-quot-or-quot-self-quot-keyword

```
class Demo
{
    private static $name;
    private $age;

    public function __construct($name, $age) 
    {
        self::$name = $name;
        $this->age=$age;
    }   

    public function show()
    {       
        echo "Name : ", self::$name, "<br/>";   //Accessing by self
        echo "Name : ", Demo::$name, "<br/>";   //Accessing by class name 
        echo "Age  : ", $this->age, "<br/>";    
    } 
}

$demo = new Demo("Tiny", 13);
$demo->show();
```

This produces the following output.

```
Name : Tiny
Name : Tiny
Age : 13
```

What is the difference between `self::$name` and `Demo::$name` in the preceding snippet?

---

```
class Person1
{
    private $name;
    private $address;

    public function __construct($name,$address)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->address = $address;
    }

    public function show()
    {
        echo "Name    : ", $this->name, "<br/>";    
        echo "Address : ", $this->address, "<br/>";  //Accessing by this
    }
}

$p1=new Person1("xxx", "yyy");
$p1->show();

class Person2
{
    private $name;
    private $address;

    public function __construct($name,$address)
    {
        self::$name = $name;
        self::$address = $address;
    }

    public function show()
    {
        echo "Name    : ", self::$name, "<br/>";    
        echo "Address : ", self::$address, "<br/>"; //Accessing by self 
    }
}

$p2=new Person1("xxx", "yyy");
$p2->show();
```

Preceding two classes `Person1` and `Person2` produce the same output as follows.

```
Name : xxx
Address : yyy
```

What is the difference between (as in the `Preson1` class, the `show()` method)

```
$this->name;
$this->address;
```

and (as in the `Preson2` class, the `show()` method)

```
self::$name;
self::$address;
```

**in this context**?

Comment: In **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1189663/170194)**, you'll find an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Demo::$name` and `self::$name` from within the `Demo` class is, in effect, the same. You can access it by name due to the fact that the the variable is static and accessible, just like you'd be able to access a *public* static variable from a different class using the classes' name, for example.

So in that case, accessing by name is mostly just a by-product of being able to access *any* public static variable from an accessible class.

The second output produces the same as the first because you're apparently creating a new `Person1` object, not a `Person2` object (see: `$p2=new Person1("xxx", "yyy");`)

If you were to create a `Person2` object, then you'd get an error, because you can't assign values to a static variable that hasn't been declared (you've got object-level variables in `name` and `address`, but not static). If you declared them as `static`, then you'd get the same output from the modified `show` method due to the fact that it's using a static call.

If you're not sure what the difference between object (read: instance) variables and static variables are, then i encourage you to partake in some Googling, but basically static variables exist at the class level, not the object level, and are accessible from any class method or object of the specified type (so if you had 100 instances of `Person2` they'd all have access to the *same* `name` variable, for example), whereas instance variables are unique to the individual object itself.

Comment: That was indeed a mistake I made and it was a major source of my confusion. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

In your first example `self::$name` and `Demo::$name` are effectively the same if used inside the `Demo` class.

Your second example should result in an error, since you haven't declared static `$name` and `$address` properties and are accessing them. It works in your case because you're creating an instance of `Person1` (possibly unintentionally):

```
$p2=new Person1("xxx", "yyy");
```

Comment: That was indeed a mistake I made and it was a major source of my confusion. Thanks very much.