# Abstract And Static Method

Tags: php

I am creating a database connection class as an abstract in the super-class. Am using PDO in php. I want to make it abstract so that i can declare specific database connection sub-classes for mysql, oracle, postgre, etc.

I have a connection method in the abstract super-class that i have also declared as abstract. My problem now is, can i make this connection method also static in the sub-class? I want to know if it is the right thing to do.

**EDIT**

```
//SUPER CLASS
abstract protected function connectToDatabase($hostname, $dbName, $userName, $password="");


// SUB CLASS
public static function connectToDatabase($hostname, $dbName, $userName, $password=""){

        $this->setHostName($hostname);
        $this->setDbName($dbName);
        $this->setUserName($userName);
        $this->setPassword($password);
        $this->setDatabaseType(DATABASE_TYPE);
        $dsn = $this->getDatabaseType(DATABASE_TYPE) . ":" . parent::getHostConst() . "=" 
              . $this->getHostName() . ";" . parent::getDbNameConst() . "=" . $this->getDbName();
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $passwd);
        $this->setPdoConnection($pdo);
}
```

Comment: What does your code look like now?

Comment: @BrendanLong at the moment i haven't written much but the two most important methods are in the updated post.

Comment: What is the point of all this? PDO already supports mysql and postgresql, and oracle. Seems like you are only hardcoding, making it all less maintainable.

Comment: The abstract definition is instance, whereas your subclass definition is static - you need to choose between the two.

Comment: (Easy does it @tereško - I read a lot of your knowledgeable comments, but I wonder if you need to go easier on people who ask questions here. Everyone has to start somewhere :-).

Comment: @tereško You are right but the arguments the PDO takes for those databases are different. For instance in Mysql you must supply a string of "mysql". So i wanted to have different sub-classes for each connection. Maybe am doing it wrong so you can direct me to the right path. thanks for your comments

Comment: @halfer can i make both static?

Comment: Marko, also: are you writing this database class as an educational exercise? If so, fine. If you intend to use it in production, there are likely to be database wrappers already in existence that would suit your requirements, and they may be stable and well-tested.

Comment: @halfer is for production. Am new in this forum so am trying to find my way. Can you point me to some of the wrappers you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, you can make both static if you wish; as it stands, it won't compile. The static/non-static nature of an abstract method and its implementation must be the same.

Comment: Depends how much abstraction you want. If you do a web search for 'PDO wrapper' there's loads of results. If you want object-based results and a query system (i.e. generally full insulation from your db engine) then look at Propel, Doctrine, PHP Active Record and NoORM. But bear in mind that learning one of those fully is quite a substantial task (ORMs in general tend to have their champions and opponents, so read up).

Comment: @MarkoMorris , it is called DSN. YOU write the whole thing in the configuration, instead of generating it from bunch of pointless constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at your code i would say you can't make them static as you are then refering to $this in them. What should $this mean in a static method?
A static method only exists once in the class and not does not refer to a special object.

For example take a look at: [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

Answer (score 0):

What you’re saying in your abstract base class is that sub-classes should implement this function signature:

```
abstract protected function connectToDatabase($hostname, $dbName, $userName, $password="");
```

You’re requiring sub-classes to implement connectToDatabase() as a protected method, but then you implement it as public in your sub-class.

Unless you really know what you’re doing, forget about the base class with the abstract method and just create a single class with a non-static method. Just keep it simple.