# Passing data in PHP Singleton between hook calls

Tags: php, drupal-7

I've created a simple Drupal module which is using a singleton design pattern to preserve data between hook calls. However, this doesn't appear to be saving the data as I'd hope.

Also this seems to be a PHP understanding problem and not Drupal, but in case someone has a Drupal tip, here is what I'm doing.

**The singleton setup**

```
class TempStore {
  private $_fileName;
  public function getFileName() { return $_fileName; }
  public function setFileName($fileName) { $_fileName = $fileName; }

  function __construct() {

  }
}

function MYMODULE_data() {
  static $data;

  if (!isset($data))
    $data = new TempStore();

  return $data;
}
```

The trouble is seen even within the same function.

```
function MYMODULE_file_insert($file) {
  $token = $file->timestamp;
  MYMODULE_data()->setFileName($token);

  // error message: Notice: Undefined variable: _fileName in TempStore->getFileName()  
  $checkVal = MYMODULE_data()->getFileName();
}
```

The error message is

> Notice: Undefined variable: _fileName in TempStore->getFileName()

Since this happens in the same function call, I believe this is a failure in my understanding of how PHP handles this sort of thing and not really related to Drupal.

Can someone see what is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not C++:

```
public function getFileName() { return $_fileName; }
public function setFileName($fileName) { $_fileName = $fileName; }
```

Should be:

```
public function getFileName() { return $this->_fileName; }
public function setFileName($fileName) { $this->_fileName = $fileName; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should refer to your field with `$this` keyword:

```
 public function getFileName() { return $this->_fileName; }
```

And in the setter as well of course:

```
public function setFileName($fileName) { $this->_fileName = $fileName; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to access `$_fileName` with `$this->_fileName`. Unrelated to your question but you should declare your static `$data` object as `private static $data` in the class that method is used in, outside of the function - then refer to that variable as `self::$data` when you test it, set it, and return it.

Comment: Thank you for the added details. I wasn't aware of the `self` accessor.

Comment: No prob. Here's more info on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this