# Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

i have this class for connect to `mysql` database using `php`/`mysqli`:

```
class AuthDB {
    private $_db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME)
        or die("Problem connect to db. Error: ". mysqli_error());
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->_db->close();
        unset($this->_db);
    }
}
```

now, i have any page for list user :

```
require_once 'classes/AuthDB.class.php';

session_start();

$this->_db = new AuthDB(); // error For This LINE
$query = "SELECT Id, user_salt, password, is_active, is_verified FROM Users where email = ?";
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($query);

        //bind parameters
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

        //execute statements
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            //bind result columnts
            $stmt->bind_result($id, $salt, $pass, $active, $ver);

            //fetch first row of results
            $stmt->fetch();

            echo $id;


        }
```

now, i see this error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in LINE 6
```

How to fix this error?!

Comment: $this only exists within the class definition its self, so you cannot use it outside of a class

Comment: `$this` refers to the class when you're **inside** a class. Outside of it it has no meaning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like the error says, you can't use `$this` outside of the class definition. To use `$_db` outside the class definition, first make it `public` instead of `private`:

`public $_db`

Then, use this code:

```
$authDb = new AuthDb();
$authDb->_db->prepare($query); // rest of code is the same
```

--

You have to understand what `$this` actually means. When used inside a class definition, `$this` is used to refer to an object of that class. So if you had a function `foo` inside `AuthDB`, and you needed to access `$_db` from within `foo`, you would use `$this` to tell PHP that you want the `$_db` from the same object that `foo` belongs to.

You might want to read this StackOverflow question: [PHP: self vs $this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/php-self-vs-this)

Comment: thanks useful answer! i change `private $_db` to `public $_db` in my class  and replace `$authDb` with `$this` my error is fixed BUT i see new error :` Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in` how to fix this error? where's my problem?

Comment: @B.BKing you might want to open a new question, but it's likely because your `$query` is invalid.