# How to redirect to another action in Controller_Template?

Tags: php, redirect, kohana, kohana-3

I've this class that extends Controller_Template.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');


    abstract class Controller_Common extends Controller_Template {

        public $template = 'main';

        public function before()
        {
            parent::before();
            View::set_global('title', 'Мій сайт');              
            View::set_global('description', 'Сайт');
            $this->template->content = '';
            $this->template->styles = array('style');
            $this->template->scripts = '';
        }

    } // End Common
```

In controller class I want to redirect to another action.

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

class Controller_User extends Controller_Common {
    public function action_info()
    {
        $this->template->content = View::factory('user/info')
            ->bind('user', $user);

        // Load the user information
        $user = Auth::instance()->get_user();

        // if a user is not logged in, redirect to login page
        if (!$user)
        {
            Request::current()->redirect('user/login');
        }
    }
    public function action_login() 
    {
    try{

        if (HTTP_Request::POST == $this->request->method()) 
        {
            // Attempt to login user
            $remember = array_key_exists('remember', $this->request->post()) ? (bool) $this->request->post('remember') : FALSE;
            $username = $this->request->post('username');
            $password = $this->request->post('password');
            $user = Auth::instance()->login($username, $password, true);

            $logged = Auth::instance()->logged_in('login');

            // If successful, redirect user
            if($user) 
            {
            $this->redirect("user/info");
            } 
            else 
            {
                $message = 'Login failed';
            }
        }
        /**/
        }catch(Exception $e)
        {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
        $this->template->content = View::factory('user/login')
            ->bind('message', $message);
    }

    public function action_logout() 
    {
        /*// Log user out
        Auth::instance()->logout();

        // Redirect to login page
        Request::current()->redirect('user/login');*/
    }

}
?>
```

I use this code in action_login

```
$this->redirect("user/info");
```

But redirection doesn't work. How to fix this problem?
I use Kohana 3.3.0 version

Answer (score 2):

`Request` class has no `redirect` method. See [userguide](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/upgrading#redirects-http-300-301-302-303-307):

```
HTTP::redirect('user/login', 302);
```

or

```
self::redirect('user/login', 302);
```

PS. `Controller::redirect()` is a [static method](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/Controller.php#L125), so userguide example seems to be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Remove try..catch from action_login, http::redirect use exceptions for redirect, [HTTP::Redirect](https://github.com/kohana/core/blob/3.3/master/classes/Kohana/HTTP.php#L31).

P.S. You can use **$this** or **self** for redirect, [$this vs self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this)