# The good way to call a private static method?

Tags: php, oop

This question could seem dumb but both ($this and self) works to call a static method.

However, what is the correct way?

I personally tend to use "self" because the private static method is like an utility function which doesn't use any object states.

```
$data = self::calcSoldeNextMonths('sl', $data, $toSub);
$data = $this->calcSoldeNextMonths('sl', $data, $toSub);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this. So self for static, this for non-static

Comment: Is declaring private static methods make sense? I always use public static method :)

Comment: all static method should be call with `static` or `self`

Comment: @Adam yes it makes a sense to use `private` over `public` or `protected`

Comment: @Glavić Nothing happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I, personally, would prefer `self::`, as it instantly tells me that I am dealing with a static method. It certainly wouldn't be much fun to dig around code where I would have to constantly look up the function declarations just to be sure what context this method operates in.

**EDIT**
Please see @Kakawait's link in the first comment: [When to use self vs this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this). Check out the second most upvoted answer for implications using `self` (namely the scope resolution).

Comment: I just find strange that no error/notice is displayed when $this is used to call a static method.

Comment: Well, just another PHP quirk to mess with the good people out there.

Answer (score 1):

Static methods should only be called with ***static::*** or ***self::***

***self::*** means the class and ***this->*** means the current object. And by definition static methods are object independent class methods, i prefer to use ***self::***

Comment: Not quite, there's also the `static::` keyword to consider from PHP version 5.3 and up.

Comment: @aefxx `static` is used for late static bindings which can be used to reference the called class in a context of static inheritance please refer o http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php‎

Comment: @Shushant The responder edited his answer. He first stated that: *"[...] the only correct way is **self::*"**.   Which is not quite true, as I've merely pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

here is simple example that differentiate  `self` and `static` and simple way to remember different b/w both of them

self returns the base instance of base object (where self is called)

static returns the current instance of object (either object is extended).

```
class BaseClass {

public function make()
{
    echo __METHOD__, "\n";
}

public function println()
{
    static::make();
}
}

class BaseClass2{

public function make()
{
    echo __METHOD__, "\n";
}

public function println()
{
    self::make();
}
}

class StaticClass extends BaseClass{

public function make()
{
    echo __METHOD__;
}
}

 class selfMain extends BaseClass2{
public function make()
{
    echo __METHOD__;
}
 }
$obj = new StaticClass();
$obj->println();//return the current instance of object

$obj = new selfMain();
$obj->println();//return the best instance of object
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer but I know what is the difference between `$this` and `self`. This is not the question.