# is it good to use self:: or static:: on non static function?

Tags: php, static, late-static-binding

i am doing some oop in php and when i just wanted to know if its good to do this?
when i use `$this->functionName()`, it works fine and i even tried with self:: and static:: and they work as i expected:

self:: will use the parent method implementation and static will use the last implementation of the method if overridden (late static binding). but the problem is that it is being used on a non static function. is this good? does it has any drawbacks?? why shouldn't i use it?

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189663/878514) for detailed description.

In general, it is possible to do the things you describe and PHP allows it. But remember that people are used to polymorphism and method overridding so if your base class allows to override some method and then, uses a `self` to call it, it will be weird that I can't change the class behavior, although it exposes it in its API as `public` or `protected` method.

IMO, it violates the [Principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment), referenced in Uncle Ben's Clean Code book.

Also, there are some differences between `static` and `$this` bindings, because `static` will always try to reference the element in the narrower, not always appropriate scope. This behavior is presented in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#example-229), and is explained in the note above, which I reference here:

> In non-static contexts, the called class will be the class of the object instance. Since `$this->` will try to call private methods from the same scope, using `static::` may give different results. Another difference is that `static::` can only refer to static properties.

Thus, although it is possible to use `static` in some places where `$this` is appropriate, the `static` keywords was introduced to use access static methods and fields and using it for another purposes should be considered confusing.

Comment: this does not fully answer my question.
we can use self::methodName() instead of $this->methodName()... but is it good to do that??? the problem of polymorphism will not arise if we use static::methodName() because it will be the same as $this->methodName...

so why not self:: / static:: vs $this-> ???

Comment: please see my edits as I provided more arguments against using `static` for non-static methods

Comment: @user2707590 Using the wrong accessor is not only confusing but also generates a warning message!