# using self instead of this variable

Tags: php

I'm reading a book of php and found this code:

```
class Employee {
        static public $NextID = 1;
        public $ID;

        public function _ _construct( ) {
                $this->ID = self::$NextID++;
        }

        public function NextID( ) {
                return self::$NextID;
        }
}
```

why here is used `self::$NextID++;` can I use like this:

```
$this-ID = $this->$NextID++;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a class is called statically `ie. ClassName::someMethod()`, there is no "instance" of the class.

Since `$this` refers to the instance of the class, $this will not exist when your class is used statically. (so $this will only be available when you created an object of your class by using `$var = new ClassName()`)

`self` refers to the class (not the object) so in static classes you can use `self::..` to refer to properties or methods within the class.

Comment: Its not `$self` is just `self`, or `static`

Answer (score 1):

Because in php you have to reference static functions with self.

There was also an explanation on stackoverflow already: [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this)

Comment: Also note that it is valid to call static methods with `$this` in the same class.