# Object oriented php object,class and methods

Tags: php, oop, object

`$Clint_ip=$this->request->clintIp();`

May I get a clear concept about this line?In here I know $clint_ip is a variable,but what is the next three?which one is an object?
which one is a method?
which one is a class?

I just need to understand this line.In several project I have seen this types of line.In this line which one called object?If you want You can give another example.In here $this is an object?or class?or method?

Comment: Could you provide some context for this code?

Comment: I just need to understand this line.In several project I have seen this types of line.In this line which one called object?If you want You can give another example.In here $this is an object?or class?or method?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `$Clint_ip` is an variable,

1. Like other object oriented based programming languages `$this` is the `this` of a class consisting it. (For more about this [When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/151969/829533))
2. `request` looks like an object of another class
3. and `clintIp()` is the `public` method of the class of the `request` object

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided appears to be from inside of a class.

---

A class is denoted like this:

```
class Example {
    private $foo;
    public $bar;

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function method() {

    }

    private function other() {

    }
}
```

When you create an object of this class, you can use the format:

```
$example = new Example();
```

This calls the constructor `__construct()`.

Once you have created ("instantiated") this object, you can use the -> to call the properties of the object.

So, I can say

```
$example->bar = "Foo";
```

which sets this property to a string.

---

#### Your Code

In your code, the property "request" is itself an object (an instance of a class).

```
$Clint_ip=$this->request->clintIp();
```

Here is an example of the code this could be using

```
class Example {
    public $request;

    public function __construct($request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

}

class Request {
    public function clintIp() {
        //return something
    }
}
```

And then some context:

```
$request = new Request;
$example = new Example($request);

$clint_ip = $example->request->clintIp();
```

So here, `$clint_ip` is the variable. `$example` and `$request` are objects (instances of classes), and `clintIp()` is a method of the request object.

Now, about "$this". This indicates that it is within the object "Example":

Imagine the class Example now has a method

```
public function test() {
    return $this->request->clintIp();
}
```

`$this` means that it is inside of an instance of an object. In `static` context, use "self::", as mentioned in one of the other answers.

Comment: Very good example,thanks a lot.Now all is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are inside object which has request property. Request property contains object with method clintIp() which return client ip.

Comment: So,request is a property of a class?Which one is a class?There have any class?