# PHP: Call an internal (Function) method within the same class

Tags: php, class, static-methods

Rather than having multiple lines of the same code on each method, I want to set up a (Boot/initialization) method to define common values and such. Then, call that method when needed.

Initially, I had something like this:

```
<?php
class boot {
    private static $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';


    public static function load() {
        return self::$root;
    }
}

$test = boot::load();
echo $test;
?>
```

But I would get an error saying something like: **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in...**

So, I changed it to:

```
<?php /* Class Bootstrap (Boot for short) */
class boot {
    private static $base = null;
    private static $root = null;


    private static function boot(){
        self::$base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';
    }


    public static function load() {
        self::boot();
        return self::$base;
    }
}

$test = boot::load();
echo $test;
?>
```

Then I got this: **Fatal error: Constructor boot::boot() cannot be static in...**

So I resorted to:

```
<?php
class boot {
    private static $base = null;
    private static $root = null;


    private function boot(){
        $this->base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';
    }


    public static function load() {
        $this->boot();
        return self::$base;
    }
}

$test = boot::load();
echo $test;
?>
```

But I am still geting an error, **Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in...**
I tried different things but I am out of ideas.

Comment: `self::$base` and `self::ini()`

Comment: @mark-baker That did not work. could you try it, in an answer?

Comment: [Read the documentation](http://php.net/oop/).

Comment: I really don't get it. If you are using an all-static class, simply initialize static variables once. If you're planning on instanciating your class, put the initializations where they belong, i.e. in the constructor. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @kuroineko 黒い猫, $base is used several times. I am also calling functions like boot:function() . Static functions cannot call a construct. Also, in this example you only see one line, but I have more. adding the same line of code over and over is not productive

Comment: 僕の名前を書いてくれてありがとう ;) Could you give us a more explicit example of your current (working) code? What you describe does not seem unusual to me, so I don't see why you would want a specific mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following

```
class boot {
    private static $base = null;
    private static $root = null;

    public static function load() {
        self::$base = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/';
        return self::$base;
    }
}

$test = boot::load();
echo $test;
```

Comment: That sure works,. What I fail to see is the point in jumping through all these hoops .

Comment: @kuroi, true, I don't see the point either.. just wanted to show the difference in Class variables and instance variables. Omar has to read on that more I am sure.

Comment: Yes, I think he would better :)

Comment: multiply load() twenty times over, with different functions. It is not what I am looking for. I want to initialize some properties in one blow. not on every function (x 20). Again, this is just one line, but I got lots more

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use $ this in a static context.

[When to use self over $this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this)

To sum up the above answer you have to use $this
 To access the members that belong to the current Object (non-static) but use self :: to access the class's static members.

You could make all your functions static and use self :: instead of $this-> .

Comment: Can you please explain? I don't understand

Comment: I have updated my answer. May I ask why you are using static variables anyway?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already tied it. I edited the question to reflect it