# Codigniter 2 - call function from extended class

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

First disclaimer - I have inhered project, and there is a lot of legacy code which I can't delete (I can delete it, but then I will need to spend few months to write everything from scratch). I extended all the models with custom **MY_Model** (it is extending the core) which have **save** function. Also most of old models have save function. 
My question is this:

How can I call the **save** function from MY_Model, and not from the class that is extending MY_Model? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about the implementation but when you want to call a static function in current class not the class that extends it you can use :-

```
self::save();
```

See it elaborated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1189663/2489860