# Trouble connecting to Database (php)

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I am working on a user database and have it set up so that the dropdown menus in my registration form take their values from tables in the database. The problem is that when I tested it out, the dropdowns were empty. Naturally the first thing I did was to go and check my connection. To connect to the database, I have a file called `BaseDAO.php` which contains the following:

```
<?php

    class BaseDAO {

        const SQL_HOST = "localhost";
        const SQL_USER = "user6538";
        const SQL_PW = "sdWf234Fg";
        const SQL_DB = "userDB";

        protected $con = null;

        function connect() {
            $this->con = mysql_connect(self::SQL_HOST, self::SQL_USER, self::SQL_PW);
            if(!$this->con) {die('Could not connect to MySQL host: ' . self::SQL_HOST . ' Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
            echo "Connected!"; //NOTE: I only just added this to test it
            mysql_select_db(self::SQL_DB);
        }

        function close() {
           mysql_close($this->con);
        }

    }

?>
```

So to test it, I added `echo "Hello World!";` outside of the class, just as a reference, then I added `connect();` right below it. I opened my page and only saw the `Hello World!` ... So then I tried `echo connect();` and again nothing. Then I tried this:

```
$baseDAO = new BaseDAO();
$baseDAO->connect();
```

And still there was nothing. Then I commented out the entire class and just added this:

```
<?php

    //...
    //Commented out class
    //.... 

    function connect() {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user6538", "sdWf234Fg" );
        if(!$con) { echo "3"; die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
        echo "Connected!";
    }

    echo "Hello World!";
    connect();

?>
```

Lo and behold the output was this:

```
Hello World!Connected!
```

I don't understand why my class doesn't work... It explains why my dropdowns were not working, since their DAO files require my `BaseDAO`.

Would someone care to enlighten me on what's going on here? Why won't my class work?

NOTE: I am using a friend's old project as a guide, so theoretically my `BaseDAO.php` should work, since his worked.

EDIT: Corrected the arguments in the second connect() function

Comment: add public in front of your functions `public function connect()`

Comment: Still didn't work...

Comment: You have commented out the class, but still in your function you are using `self::SQL_HOST`, how is it working? It surely calling the function, but your arguments have no meaning to mysql_connect function

Comment: public $con ? and use MySQLi or PDO instead off mysql cause its deprecated.

Comment: Oops, sorry that was just a copy-paste error. I actually replaced it with the actual localhost, username, etc... I will correct.

Comment: I tested your code (with class) and it works. Could you please check your php error.log file and see what error you are getting. Also please do not use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated. Instead use either mysqli or PDO.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? If your friend's PHP version is higher than your, then that could explain it. Plus, if error reporting isn't on, do. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php which may signal possible errors.

Comment: Tested fine on PHP Version 5.2.17 => `Connected!` - Check your DB credentials also, while using `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` if you're not already doing so. This http://stackoverflow.com/q/151969/ may also be of help.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I doubt he used a higher version, his project is from last year.
PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm not sure how to use `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ? Where do I put that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did `phpinfo();`

Comment: Place that underneath your opening `<?php` tag. Edit: Sorry, I thought you were someone else lol Edited/comment about PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok so i got this: `Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context on line 15` I had no idea about using error reporting, I was coding blindly :S Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Now you know what to go after ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! Lifesaver!

Comment: You're very much welcome. Using [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is definitely a tool worthy for developers, *cheers* ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
class BaseDAO {

    private static $SQL_HOST = "localhost";
    private static $SQL_USER = "user6538";
    private static $SQL_PW = "sdWf234Fg";
    private static $SQL_DB = "userDB";

    protected static $con = null;

    public static function connect() {
        self::con = mysql_connect(self::SQL_HOST, self::SQL_USER, self::SQL_PW);
        if(!self::con) {die('Could not connect to MySQL host: ' . self::SQL_HOST . ' Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
        echo "Connected!"; //NOTE: I only just added this to test it
        mysql_select_db(self::SQL_DB);
    }

    public static function close() {
       mysql_close(self::con);
    }

}
```

To connect do the following no need to create an instance of the class because its static:

```
BaseDAO::connect();
```

Comment: how are you trying to call the functions? What error does it give?

Comment: I'm calling it right outside the class. when I open the page, it's simply blank.. even my Hello World won't print now...

Comment: So you don't have error_reporting on? Just add this under your class `BaseDAO::connect();`

Comment: I did, nothing happened.

Comment: Oh `$this->con` should be `self::con`

Answer (score 0):

The return value of mysql_connect is FALSE in an error case. 0 is a positive value.
To be sure, make this change:

```
    if(self::con === FALSE) {die('Could not connect to MySQL host: ' . self::SQL_HOST . ' Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
```

Your second SQL, where you did remove the CLASS parts, cannot work, but it strangely does.

```
$con = mysql_connect(self::SQL_HOST, self::SQL_USER, self::SQL_PW);
```

You do not have the self:: constants defined if you class does not exist. PHP should have produced an error message in this case. So your description is wrong and missing something.