# Recursive copy undefined function

Tags: php

I have a recursive copy function that should copy all files from a directory to another, but it gives an error. This is the function;

```
public function cpy($source, $dest){
    if(is_dir($source)) {
        $dir_handle=opendir($source);
        while($file=readdir($dir_handle)){
            if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                if(is_dir($source."/".$file)){
                    if(!is_dir($dest."/".$file)){
                        mkdir($dest."/".$file);
                    }
                    cpy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
                } else {
                    copy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir_handle);
    } else {
        copy($source, $dest);
    }
}
```

The error given is `Fatal error: Call to undefined function cpy() in /var/www/Deployer/include/deployer.class.php on line 14`

This function is also in a class.

Comment: where is `cpy` is defined and what is in deployer.class.php line 14?

Comment: At least try to understand the error message. Look you made typo `cpy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);`

Comment: @Lashane `cpy` is defined directly at the top of the code shown in the question... also, line 14 is the line calling `cpy`

Comment: @Core it looks like it class method, so you should use `$this->cpy(...` to call it

Comment: @ShaifulIslam this is **recursive copy** the `copy` function would not work.

Comment: it should not be `cpy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);` because you are calling a function of a class. See Riad's solution.Hope you will learn first how to call member function of a class from another member function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using any class? then you should use:

```
$this->cpy(...)
```

Or remove the `public` infront of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$this ->`

```
public function cpy($source, $dest){
    if(is_dir($source)) {
        $dir_handle=opendir($source);
        while($file=readdir($dir_handle)){
            if($file!="." && $file!=".."){
                if(is_dir($source."/".$file)){
                    if(!is_dir($dest."/".$file)){
                        mkdir($dest."/".$file);
                    }
                    $this->cpy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);// use the $this keyword here
                } else {
                    copy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir_handle);
    } else {
        copy($source, $dest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably beacause you are in a class.

Try this instead :

```
self::cpy($source."/".$file, $dest."/".$file);
```

Comment: Yeah but i think this is more apporiate and PHP allow to use it even if we don't add the static keywords http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this