# How to login using two different model or switch identity class in yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

I want to allow user login from two different model.

*Config.php*

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User', //one more class here
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout' => 3600*2,
    ],
```

*LoginForm.php*

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        // username and password are both required
        [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
        // rememberMe must be a boolean value
        ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
        // password is validated by validatePassword()
        ['password', 'validatePassword'],
    ];
}

 public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
{
    if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
            $this->addError($attribute, Yii::t('user', 'Incorrect username or password.'));
        }
    }
}

public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public function parentLogin()
{
    // How to validate parent Login?
}

public function getUser()
{
    if ($this->_user === false) {
        $this->_user = User::findByUsername($this->username);
    }

    return $this->_user;
}
```

*User.php*

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public static function tableName()
   {
    return 'users';
   }

   public static function findIdentity($id)
  {
    return static::findOne($id);
  }

  public static function findByUsername($username)
 {
    return static::findOne(['user_login_id' => $username]);
 }
```

*Controller.php*

```
 public function actionLogin()
{
    // Working
}

public function actionParentLogin()
{
    $model = new LoginForm();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->parentLogin()) {

            $parent = ParentLogin::find()->where(['p_username' => $model->p_username])->one();
        if($parent){
            \Yii::$app->session->set('p_id',$parent->p_id);
            return $this->redirect(['parent-dashboard']);
        }
        else
        {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', Yii::t('site', 'Incorrect username or password.'));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('parent-login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
}
```

I don't know how to validate parent login. I tried for hours finding workaround but not succeed.

I am stuck on `Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);` because user table don't have parent login records.

**My questions**

1) Is it possible to have two `identityClass`. If yes then how? 
2) Is it possible to extend `ParentLogin` model to `User`. If yes then how to validate?

**References**

[How To extend user class?](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/issues/6)
[Customising the CWebUser class](http://chris-backhouse.com/cook-your-own-user-authentication-in-yii-part-2/990)
[Custom userIdentity class in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27836662/custom-useridentity-class-in-yii2)

Comment: Have you already tried to extend a class that you want to in User.php?

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes. I tried that but doesn't succeeded. so, roll-backed changes.

Comment: I always do this way... I use the default model and extend one of mine modifying the functions of default model with `findOne's`

Comment: @GuilhermeLopes. Can you please elaborate it with answer. It has taken my half day to solve.

Comment: I don't uderstand why you need tow separate tables and models for this situation. Why not just add an extraa column to your `user` table, call it isParent and set it to `boolean`. Then you can just test if it's true, do something, if it's false, do something else. Then you are just using one model, one set of validation, and two views depending on the value of `isParent`

Comment: @JoeMiller. If i merge two tables then number of records exceed the boundaries of database. For boolean suggestion, not applicable, because i already have three different user in `User` model. I have separate login for `parentLogin` model.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Joe Miller has a good sugestion about having one user class and some boolean fields in users' table to check user's role, as an alternative to rbac. But since in your situation it is not possible, here is what I can suggest to you (this approach is half-way tested and need to be adopted).

Yes you can have two or more identityClasses, but not in the same time. You need to handle switching between identities. So first, I suggest to you edit your `LoginForm` model a little:

```
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;
    // we added this parameter to handle userModel class
    // that is responsible for getting correct user
    public $userModel;

    private $_user = false;

    /* all other methods stay same */

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            // calling findByUsername method dynamically
            $this->_user = call_user_func(
                [$this->userModel, 'findByUsername'], 
                $this->username
            );
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

Now in controller:

```
public function actionParentLogin()
{
    $model = new LoginForm(['userModel' => ParentLogin::className()]);
    // calling model->login() here as we usually do
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
            // no need to worry about checking if we found parent it's all done polymorphycally for us in LoginForm
            // here is the trick, since we loggin in via parentLogin action we set this session variable.
            Yii::$app->session->set('isParent', true);
            return $this->redirect(['parent-dashboard']);
        } else {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('error', Yii::t('site', 'Incorrect username or password.'));
        }
    }
    return $this->render('parent-login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
}
```

Your `parentLogin` model should extends `User` model to make all this work:

```
class parentLogin extends User
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        //you parent users table name
        return 'parent_users';
    }

    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
         return static::findOne(['p_username' => $username]);
    }
}
```

Now when you logged in, you need to handle identity switch, because in the configuration you have `'identityClass' => 'app\models\User'`. We can use `bootstrap` property for that:

```
//in your config file
'bootstrap' => [
    'log',
    //component for switching identities
    'app\components\IdentitySwitcher'
],
```

IdentitySwitcher class:

```
class IdentitySwitcher extends Component implements BootstrapInterface
{
    public function bootstrap($app)
    {
        //we set this in parentLogin action
        //so if we loggin in as a parent user it will be true
        if ($app->session->get('isParent')) {
            $app->user->identityClass = 'app\models\ParentLogin';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. @Tony. Checking it.

Comment: Ok, let me know how it goes

Comment: **what is component for switching identity** in `config`

Comment: sorry, not getting it. [Yii chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99406/yii-warriors)

Comment: you need to create a class. I called it `IdentitySwitcher` in this example. So you need to create a directory _components_ and there create _IdentitySwitcher.php_ file in it, with content from example

Comment: Can you please visit yii chat room.

Answer (score 1):

** Edit, this doesn't work, you can only have one identity class **
** Ref https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5134 **
I would suggest trying the following - not tested.

In your config, add an extra identity interface, as you suggest;

```
'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout' => 3600*2,
    ],
'parent' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Parent',
        'enableAutoLogin' => false,
        'authTimeout' => 3600*2,
    ],
```

Your `Parent` model can then either extend the `User` model, which will give the same validation methods as the original `User` model, or implement `IdentityInterface` from scratch. From your column names in your `parent` table, I'd suggest the second method as the columns are different to the `User` table.

You would then need two `loginForms`: `loginForm` and `parentLoginForm`, as the validation is different in each case.

Then, in your controller, you can call the appropriate login form as required.

Comment: I have already tried, It won't work. it gives first 'missing class' error and after adding gives `identity` error.

Comment: Yup, just found out this won't work, only a single identity class is supported. I'll leave this here so people know it won't work!