# Add multiple tables for login in web.config

Tags: mysql, yii2

I developing a site with two different registrations, and I have 2 different table, One is user and 2nd is admin.In the web.config how to I can set both tables in the components section. For this I am tried this my code is that :-

```
 'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\Users',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        //'class' => 'yii\web\User'
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\adminUser',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ],
```

But when run run my application its showing error message  erro message is that :-
       Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException
I also tried this [multiple user identity in config Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35254678/multiple-user-identity-in-config-yii2) when I add class its showing blank page.
Thank you

Comment: What is the exact error message? You need `'class' => 'yii\web\User'` in `admin` component, uncomment it.

Comment: @Bizely when I uncomment this line its showing blank website  and when I comment its  then error isInvalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException

The configuration for the "admin" component must contain a "class" element.

Comment: Leave it uncommented and remove the `enableAutoLogin` key. If this not helps check the runtime log and/or server log for other errors.

Comment: Tough road. Already asked question : [How to login using two different model or switch identity class in yii2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34959941/how-to-login-using-two-different-model-or-switch-identity-class-in-yii2)